# Why it's impossible in java to refer non-final variable in inner anonymous class?

Tags: java, closures, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different)

Why it's impossible in java to refer non-final variable in inner anonymous class? Simple answer would be "Because it's prohibited", but I'd like to know, WHY did they prohibit this useful functionality? Maybe there are some sort of abilities Java lacks of or it's designed in the "wrong" way. I'd like to know.

Comment: Look at this post, it may help a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different

Comment: @cularis, I've looked over it but due to edits it's not clear what answer to consider correct.

Comment: Another good answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785073/why-should-my-local-variables-be-final-to-be-accessible-from-anonymous-class/4785141#4785141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that after the enclosing method returns, the local variable no longer exists. Therefore a copy of the variable is created when the anonymous class is instanciated. If Java allowed the local variable to be changed afterwards, the anonymous class would only know the old value.

The way Java does it is opposed to real [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) known from other languages.

Comment: As I see it, the prohibition exists to maintain the illusion that the anonymous class uses the variable directly rather than a copy, and to avoid people having false expectations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure that variable is copied, due to you can perfectly pass final variable, then change one of its fields inside anonymous and that change will be visible in the enclosing method.

Comment: `final` only means that the reference cannot be changed, not that the object suddenly becomes immutable. Only the reference is copied, not the object itself (the object is stored in the heap, not on the stack).

Comment: 'I'm not sure that variable is copied'. You are mistaken. It is. The original can go out of scope, so it *must* be copied.

Comment: @EJP: well, languages that support true closures manage to do it without copying the variable. Admittedly that involves a lot of behind-the-curtains magic; AFAIK stack frames that are referred to by a closure are actually allocated on the heap and thus become scope-independant.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt Of course, but this is Java ...

Comment: @EJP, yes, it is, but if the variable will be changed afterwards in the enclosing method, this change WILL be visible inside the closure, because both variables refer to the same object.

Comment: @gasan But it *can't* be changed, *because* this is Java, and the Java compiler insists that it be final, so it can't be changed. This is what we are discussing.

Comment: @gasan: The reference is copied, not the object. final behaves the same way in anonymous classes as anywhere else. Perhaps you can think of the final variables as parameters to a (hidden) constructor of the anonymous class.

Comment: @EJP I meant object behind that variable, not variable itself can be changed

Comment: @Mathias thanks, at first I thought that the object is copied.

Comment: @gasan your point eludes me. The final outer variable is copied into the inner class. Period. Nothing you have said subsequently alters or even bears on that fact.

Comment: @EJP To make myself clear: variable from enclosing code is copied into the closure that variable into the closure can be changed, also can be changed the object that is referred to outer and inner variable. Changing in copied variable won't affect outer variable.

Comment: @gasan None of this affects the invalidity of your statement 'if the variable will be changed afterwards in the enclosing method, this change WILL be visible inside the closure'. This cannot happen in Java.