# How to declare nested function for Jasmin byte code?

Tags: java, c, pascal, bytecode, jasmin

I am writing a compiler and I need to convert Mini Pascal (a simple version of Pascal) to Jasmin byte code.

1. But how do I **declare the nested function** in the Jasmin language?
2. Because `function tt(I): I` can only pass in one Integer (which is `rr`) how do I transfer the **variable `d`** from **function `ss`** to **function `tt`**?

C++ (translated from Mini Pascal by myself):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a, b;

int ss(int rr)
{
  int d;

  int tt(int rr)
  {
    int e;
    e = rr * 3;
    return rr + d - e + b;
  }

  d = rr - 4;
  return tt(rr);
}

int main()
{
  b = -5;
  a = ss(3);
  cout << a;

  return 0;
}
```

Mini Pascal:

```pascal
PROGRAM test_nested_function(input, output, error);
VAR a, b : INTEGER;

  FUNCTION ss(rr :INTEGER) : INTEGER;
  VAR d : INTEGER;

    FUNCTION tt(rr : INTEGER) : INTEGER;
    VAR e : INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      e := rr * 3;
      tt := rr + d - e + b;
    END;

  BEGIN
    d := rr - 4;
    ss := tt(rr)
  END;

BEGIN
  b := -5;
  a := ss(3);
  writelnI(a)
END.
```

Comment: I know almost nothing about Jasmin, but a quick Google search made me think that it is like an "assembly language for Java". If I am correct, why are you translating to C++, why not Java? A search for "nested functions in Java" showed me two ways to simulate nested functions in Java (one way for pre-Java 8, and the other way for Java 8 and later).

Comment: C++ also doesn't support nested functions, at least not in that form. You can do lambdas starting with C++11, but they have a different syntax. Your C++ code is not valid in any version of the language.

Comment: @Stuart You could have clicked on the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasmin) to read a short description without needing to use Google.

Answer (score 0):

When you're translating from a language that has closures to one that doesn't, you have to retain a reference to the outer function somehow. There are, broadly speaking, two ways to do that: *nested closures* and *flat closures*. The important thing to note is that, in both of these cases, your closure is *not* an ordinary top level function. It's some structure that happens to be callable.

## Nested Closures

In a nested closure, your nested function simply maintains a reference to the enclosing scope as a pointer to some abstract data structure. So, `tt` maintains a reference to `ss` (in the abstract) and then can access the `d` variable via `ss.d`. Java pseudo-code for the same:

```
public class SsStructure {
  private int rr;
  private int d;

  public SsStructure(int rr) {
    this.rr = rr;
    this.d = 0;
  }

}

public class TtStructure {
  private SsStructure closure;

  public TtStructure(SsStructure closure) {
    this.closure = closure;
  }

  public int call(int rr) {
    ...
  }
 
}

public class Main {
  public static int ss(int rr) {
    SsStructure ss = new SsStructure(rr);
    TtStructure tt = new TtStructure(ss);
    ss.d = ss.rr - 4;
    return tt.call(ss.rr - 4);
  }
}
```

In this model, your `ss` function gets a closure frame in your program. All of its local variables (or at least, those needed by the closures) get put into that structure rather than being declared as actual local variables. Then that closure structure gets passed to any nested function that needs it.

If you have functions nested multiple layers deep, then a closure maintains a reference to the immediately enclosing scope. If it needs to access variables that exist multiple layers up the closure stack, it will do so through indirect references, since each closure frame retains a reference to its *own* enclosing scope.

## Flat Closures

With flat closures, your nested function receives copies of the actual concrete variables from the enclosing scope. Your `tt` is still a structure, but rather than storing a reference to some other `ss` structure, it gets the actual `int` it needs.

```
public class TtStructure {
  private int d;

  public TtStructure(int d) {
    this.d = d;
  }

  public int call(int rr) {
    ...
  }
 
}

public class Main {
  public static int ss(int rr) {
    int d = rr - 4;
    TtStructure tt = new TtStructure(d);
    return tt.call(rr - 4);
  }
}
```

This is a more space-efficient approach. Rather than storing a bunch of pointers everywhere, you store only the actual data, and the data you need. Further, if you have nested closures, you automatically flatten them when you create these specialized structures, so there's less indirection.

However, care must be taken if you have mutable closures. If you have a `final` variable, then there's no problem. In fact, this is exactly why the [Java language forbids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662817/why-its-impossible-in-java-to-refer-non-final-variable-in-inner-anonymous-class) non-`final` variables from being closed over.

If you want to allow mutable variables in closures, you'll need to explicitly add in a layer of indirection. This can be a simple class that stores one instance variable, and then you can use that variable in both the enclosing scope *and* the closure.

```
public class Cell<T> {
  public T impl;
  public Cell(T impl) {
    this.impl = impl;
  }
}
```

You need to wrap any local variable in a `Cell<T>` if it is (a) used in a closure, *and* (b) reassigned to at any point. Variables that are `final` (hence never reassigned) need not be wrapped, and those that are only used locally (never in a closure) need not be wrapped.