# Problem in Disabling JButton in Java

Tags: java

Good day!

I want to disable a button once I click it. My code is as follows..

```
for (char buttonChar = 'a'; buttonChar <= 'z'; buttonChar++) {
        String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
        JButton letterButton = new JButton(buttonText);
        letterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
                System.out.println("actionCommand is: " + actionCommand);
                letterButton.setEnabled(false);    //I disable the button here
            }
});
```

But an error appears: `local variable letter Button is accessed from the inner class; needs to be declared final`.. What does it mean? how can i resolve the issue?
Thank you...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really have to do with *disabling* the button, but rather accessing the reference to the button at all.

You need to declare the `letterButton` as final. That is, change from

```
JButton letterButton = new ...
```

to this

```
final JButton letterButton = new ...
```

---

Here is a good explanation on *why* it needs to be final: [Why inner class can access only final variable?](http://technologiquepanorama.wordpress.com/2008/06/19/why-inner-class-can-access-only-final-variable/)

The reason is basically the following: Your local variables can not be touched by other threads. The code of the `ActionListener` will possibly be executed by another thread. By making the variable `final`, you're basically transforming it to a value. This value can then be read by several threads concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton letterButton
```

should be final because only final variables or class fields (private/public) accessible in anonymous classes. Have a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)