# General anonymous class instantiation question

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have noticed in the code in my system that someone instantiated an anonymous class as follows

```
 Class ExampleClass{

     MyObj obj; 

     methodA(new ClassA(){
         @override public void innerMethodA(){
            //code...
        }
    });
}
```

So far so good.
Now, in order to use obj that was declared before the method I usually define it as final.
I don't really understand why but i do because the compiler asks. 
In this code i see in innerMethodA() the usage of

```
 ExampleClass.this.obj()
```

without final.

My questions :
1. why do I have to put final when I use obj?
2. what is ExampleClass.this ? Notice that ExampleClass is the Class not an instance. then what is the "this"? if it has several instances?
3. What happens if I change the obj while the inner method runs (in my code inner method runs in a loop so I plan on changing it . will it explode?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You have to use `final` when you capture the variable of a *local* variable... not an *instance* variable of the enclosing class.
- `ExampleClass.this` is a reference to the instance of `ExampleClass` associated with the instance of the subclass of `ClassA`. In your case, it will be the same as `this` within `methodA`.
- It won't explode - it will just change the value of `obj`. Think of it as capturing the *value* of `ExampleClass.this` (so you can't change that) but you can change the data *within* the object referred to by `ExampleClass.this`.

Comment: 1. So, should I use every time  ExampleClass.this.obj() instead of final? 
2. Is it possible to cause a lock when I change its value ?

Comment: @user450602: It depends on what you're trying to use. For a local variable, you *do* need to make the local variable final. As for locking - you should probably make that part of the enclosing class.

Comment: @user450602: No, I mean exactly what I said. Do you understand the difference between instance variables and local variables? As for the locking part: if changing a value requires a lock to be acquired, you should write a method to do that consistently, and call that method from your inner class.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are no "true" closures (functions that capture scope) in Java. See e.g.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different
2. You can use this form to reference ambiguous methods / variables in the scope of "ExampleClass".
3. You cannot change the reference. What you *can* do is use an indirection, e.g. a final reference to an object that can swap it's values. An example would be the class of Atomic value holders, e.g. [AtomicReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Because, the way you described it, in this case, they are not using ExampleClass.this.obj, they are calling the method ExampleClass.this.obj().
2. ExampleClass.this refers to the encapsulating instance of ExampleClass in which this ClassA instance is instantiated.
3. Not necessarily.