# Java - getting loop iterator to a function inside loop?

Tags: java, loops

Kind of a silly problem I'm facing here... Basically I'm in a For-loop and within this loop I'm always calling a function to make a button. But in this function I want to pass the loop iterator as it's changing to differentiate the buttons. But then it tells me I need to make the loop iterator "final" which means it doesn't change!

Well my problem will make more sense with some skeleton code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) { 

                //some other stuff including creating the below button 'btn'

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //set some attribute based on i
                        //but when I do this it only sets based on the greatest value of i (!)
                    }
                });
}
```

Meh kinda silly problem I know... I'm new to Java though!

Cheers.

Comment: The comment saying you will set the attribute based on i using *the greatest value of i* seems inaccurate.  You shouldn't be able to compile code containing your snippet due to the lack of keyword `final` indicated in the answers.  You may have wrapped your integer in a final single element array, though, and you'd get the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) { 

    final int _i = i;

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // use _i instead of i
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `_i` must be declared `final`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this bit of silly example code:

```
int i = 0;
obj.invokeThunkAfter10Seconds(new ThunkObject() {
    public void thunk() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
i = 1;
```

The `ThunkObject` holds a reference to `i`, but `i` can change, which makes the output unpredictable and depends on when `i` is changed and when `thunk` is invoked.

Because Java doesn't have proper closures (by design, see [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different)), you are explicitly not allowed to capture non-final (i.e. changable) variables like this.

Instead you must declare the variable `final`, meaning it's initialized and then is not changable. This means you can never change `i` after it has been captured by the inner class.

```
final int i = 0;
obj.invokeThunkAfter10Seconds(new ThunkObject() {
    public void thunk() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
// Can't change i here. It will forever now be 0.
```

In your example you can't just set `i` to be final, because you do want to change the value on each loop iteration. Instead you can create a copy of the value in a final variable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) { 
    //some other stuff including creating the below button 'btn'

    final int capturedI = i;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //set some attribute based on capturedI
        }
    });
}
```