# cannot assign value to "final" variable in java

Tags: java, swing, final

```
 private void pushButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    final int c=0;
    final JDialog d=new JDialog();
    JLabel l=new JLabel("Enter the Element :");
    JButton but1=new JButton("OK");
    JButton but2=new JButton("Cancel");
    final JTextField f=new JTextField(10);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    but1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            c=Integer.parseInt(f.getText());
            d.setVisible(false);
            d.dispose( );
        }
     });
but2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        d.setVisible(false);
        d.dispose( );
    }
});
}
```

I am using netbeans 7.1.1. This is my code here i have declared 'c' as "final int" but the line "c=Integer.parseInt(f.getText());" i am getting an error "cannot assign a value to a final variable". If i am deleting the word final from the declaration and making it just as "int c" then in the same line i get an error "local variable c cannot be accessed from within a class;needs to be declared final". can anyone tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik no, this one is tagged "swing" :P

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You've got *c* declared in a function, and then you've created an anonymous inner class within that function. This inner class, the ActionListener, persists past the time your function terminates - so it can't assign values to c, because c is local to the function.

The warning about "final" is misleading - that's just the compiler telling you that you can't access transient local variables from an anonymous class. You can't solve the problem just by making c final, as that would prevent any assignment to it at all, but you can make c an *instance member* of the class pushButtonActionPerformed is in, instead. Something like this:

```
class Something
{
    int c;

    private void pushButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {
        JButton but1=new JButton("OK");
        but1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                c=Integer.parseInt(f.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The statement that "you can't access transient local variables from an anonymous class" is false. It is also false that a final variable cannot be assigned to. If that were true, there would be no such thing as a final var as it would be useless. What is actually going on is that a **closure** is created that **closes over** the variable in scope of the anonymous class declaration. Java only has the restriction that you can only close over final vars. This is to maintain thread safety.

Comment: Your code example is wrong because you have **not** made a closure, so all instances of the anonymous class will share the same int.

Comment: Aside from Marko's hating above, that was a great explanation and solved my problem. two thumbs up

Answer (score 14):

I'll skip the reasons and cut to the solution: use

```
final int[] c = {0};
...
c[0] = Integer.parseInt(f.getText());
```

For the full story refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Comment: I tried so many solutions, only this trick worked. My variable was in AsyncTask external custom class. +1

Comment: The reason is that while the address of the c[] array is forced constant with the final keyword, its contents are not: they are mutable. Up vote from me.

Answer (score 6):

> but the line "c=Integer.parseInt(f.getText());" i am getting an error "cannot assign a value to a final variable

Right. The whole point of `final` variables is that you can only assign to them once, but you're trying to assign to it twice (once in the initialization setting it to `0`, once in your quoted line). From [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A variable can be declared `final`. A `final` variable may only be assigned to once. Declaring a variable `final` can serve as useful documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid programming errors.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a `final` variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned (§16) immediately prior to the assignment.**
>
> A blank `final` is a `final` variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.
>
> Once a `final` variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a `final` variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.

*(Their emphasis, not mine.)*

Instead of trying to track the state you're storing in `c` in a variable in the method, track it in a data member in the instance of your anonymous `ActionListener` you're creating.

Comment: Make the state you're trying to track in c something you track in your anonymous ActionListener instance rather than in a variable in the surrounding function (I've updated the answer to say that).

Answer (score 2):

This is the reason that keyword `final` exists in java. The variable is final, i.e. its value cannot be changed. If you have to change the value do not mark variable as final.

Comment: This does not resolve OP's problem since he is mutating the var inside a local class.

Answer (score 0):

a variable is declared with **final** keyword means its value cannot be changed. final variable are like **constants**

Comment: This is not OP's problem. He cannot remove final as he is mutating it inside a local class.

Answer (score 0):

`final` makes the "variable" a constant--you can't change it.  As to why the compiler is giving you warnings after you delete the final keyword, we'd need to see the whole code...

EDIT:

```
 but1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
 {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         c=Integer.parseInt(f.getText());
         d.setVisible(false);
         d.dispose( );
     }
  });
```

I believe this is the segment of code that causes the compiler to fire the warning.  You can't use `c` in this class...

Answer (score -4):

Just remove the `final` keyword from the declaration and continue your program. As `final` keyword means the value is unaltered.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question -- OP has stated that he gets another error when he removes final.