# Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

I have some problem in my program.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityenter code here`_main);

    ImageView ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    ShapeDrawable d4 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());


    d4.setIntrinsicHeight(150);
    d4.setIntrinsicWidth(40);
    d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    d4.setVisible(true, true);
    ob4.setImageDrawable(d4);

    Button btn_start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Cannot refer to a non-final variable d4 inside an inner class defined in a      different method
        //But i don't want to make this field "final", becouse i will change color of this shape in future. Thanks.
        d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: you can change the color even though it is final. what you cannot do is re-define it

Answer (score 5):

Declare your field outside of your method (at class level).

Comment: but method set on click is inside in method onCreate

Comment: @user1702667 it means u have to Declare it before oncreate() method. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (no-thinking) way to do this is creating a duplicate, but a `final` reference to the very same object:

```
ShapeDrawable d4 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
final ShapeDrawable d4Final = d4;

// you can use d4Final in your inner class
```

Comment: btw the reason for you do not want to make `d4` final suggests me that you are not 100% sure what you are doing. Local variables like `d4` have usually a short life-cycle, so probably your intention is not to keep the `d4` reference final. Final makes only the local variable reference final, that let's you change things later IMHO.

Comment: I think if i make a final variable, a will not change it in future;
for exemple
final int var=3;
i cant do var=5;

Comment: primitives and object references are fundamentally different. there are mutable and immutable objects.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Before your `onCreate()` method put this

```
ShapeDrawable d4;
```

In your `onCreate` method put

```
d4 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
```

Comment: no,becouse i must create oval before button click

Comment: by this too you are creating it in onCreate() method. You are just giving reference it before onCreate() method. I had similar problem , so I know it well.

Comment: when i press start-color is changed to RED, but then i press STOP Button btn_stop = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2); btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE); } }); and color doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Just make your class implement the interface, ie:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Then have `onClick` as a class method and add it to your button like this:

```
btn_start.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You also have to make d4 an instance variable, so your class would look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ShapeDrawable d4 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityenter code here`_main);

    ImageView ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    d4.setIntrinsicHeight(150);
    d4.setIntrinsicWidth(40);
    d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    d4.setVisible(true, true);
    ob4.setImageDrawable(d4);

    Button btn_start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Cannot refer to a non-final variable d4 inside an inner class defined in a      different method
    //But i don't want to make this field "final", becouse i will change color of this shape in future. Thanks.
    d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: can you write it in my code,becouse i didn't understand how to make it

Answer (score 0):

You can make it final and than change it. Final only means that memory address of object is same.

```
final ShapeDrawable d4;
d4.setShape(new Shape());
```

it will be ok;

Comment: No,it isn't ok, becouse i can change the color of shape only onсe.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView ob4;
ShapeDrawable d4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activityenter code here`_main);

ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
d4 = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());


d4.setIntrinsicHeight(150);
d4.setIntrinsicWidth(40);
d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
d4.setVisible(true, true);
ob4.setImageDrawable(d4);

Button btn_start = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn_start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //Cannot refer to a non-final variable d4 inside an inner class defined in a      different method
    //But i don't want to make this field "final", becouse i will change color of this shape in future. Thanks.
    d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: when i press start-color is changed to RED, but then i press STOP
Button btn_stop = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
  btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    d4.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
   }
  });
 and color doesn't change