# I need to set a variable, but I also need it to be final.

Tags: java, android, final

In the following code, the first `if` statement complains that `current_guy` can't be a `final` but the second `if` statement complains that `current_guy` isn't a final. I am out of ideas.

```
final int current_guy=0;

if (a.equals("bf")){
   current_guy=1;
}

guy1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
   public void onClick(View v) {

   if (current_guy==1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
}
```

Comment: Back up.  Why do these variables need to be final?

Comment: It has to be final because it's an event listener in Java.

Comment: @Makoto: for variable to be accessible from a nested class, it needs to be final. Java rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first one is complaining is because you can't set a final variable. The reason it's complaining that it's not final is that you're creating what is called an anonymous inner class.  So your OnClickListener is a completely separate class and can't access variables from your main class at runtime.  This is why it has to be Final.  Then when the compiler is building your app it knows what that value is and can substitute it in there.  If you want to have this variable be, well variable, then you have to pass the value into the OnClickListener so that it can get the updates as the variable changes.

Comment: Hmm... using your explanation, I was able to just move it outside of my `onCreate` and now it works perfectly. I thought I tried that already, but I guess not. Any disadvantage to just moving outside of `onCreate`?

Comment: Where did you move it to?  Inside of another method?

Comment: It was inside of `onCreate` so I just moved it outside of that. Now it's a global variable.

Comment: Now it is a member variable, instead of local.  This will work since the anon inner class does have access to the container class (the answer is wrong to that effect).  As a local variable, it doesn't actually exist at a later point when the anon class is called, thus it has to be final so the jre can do in inline replacement of its value (this part was correct).

Answer (score 8):

```
final int current_guy = a.equals("bf") ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: How would I use this if I wanted to set it to multiple numbers? Like 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: @EGHDK A final variable **cannot** be set multiples times. It must be set *exactly once* before use. This is just how it works - or it wouldn't be final :)

Comment: Can I do this? `final int current_guy = a.equals("bf") ? 4 : 3 : 2 : 1 : 0`

Comment: you could chain the ternary operator :) it would be very difficult as far as readability is considered.

Comment: @EGHDK Consider this: `final int current_guy = DetermineCurrentGuy(a);` the called method can do whatever it wants - and `current_guy` will be assigned the return value once.

Answer (score 3):

Jordan Denison had this in an answer that was deleted .. not sure why, because it is correct. This is then just a *re-post* for "completeness" of the current answers. (That being said, I would likely use the ternary operator approach here.)

Note that a `final` variable's assignment can be *delayed* as long as it is assigned *exactly once* on all code-paths before use.

```
final int current_guy; // no assignment here

if (a.equals("bf"))
    {
        current_guy=1;
    }
else
    {
        current_guy=0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign current_guy to another final variable

```
final int finalCurrentGuy = current_guy;
guy1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
       if (finalCurrentGuy==1) {
         ....
       }
    }
```

This makes copy of the variable current_guy at that point in time and passes that into the inner class

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen) `SO` post explains why it must be final inside the inner class

Answer (score 2):

What i would do is :

```
int current_guy=0;

// Set the value that you want based on a condition
if (a.equals("bf"))
{
    current_guy=1;
}

final int valueToTest = current_guy;
guy1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

if (valueToTest ==1) {
    // your code
    }
}
```

The reason, this is imposed is because the `onClick()` method may execute some time later in response to an event and may be in a separate thread. Then you wont want the value of the variable to be changed either inside that handler or somewhere outside while the handler is being executed. You could say it is to prevent a dirty read of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Make another class that implements your `OnClickListener` and pass it the `current_guy` as a parameter.  This will stop it from complaining about the variable not being final.  You cannot reference non-final variables when declaring inner classes and methods like that.

Answer (score -2):

Once you check/adjust, assign `current_guy` to a final variable:

```
int current_guy=0;


if (a.equals("bf"))
    {
        current_guy=1;
    }

final int final_current_guy = current_guy;

guy1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (final_current_guy==1) {
        }
    }
```

Or use one-line assignment:

```
final int current_guy = (a.equals("bf") ? 1 : 0);
```