# How to initialize variable that defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java, wicket

It should be simple, but i can't figure it out..
I have this code:

```
Form<?> form2 = new Form<Void>("form2") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        ...
    dataView = new DataView("listview", new ListDataProvider(list));
        ...
    }
}
add(dataView);
```

How to define dataView and where?
If i try to make `final DataView dataView = null;` occur an error: `The final local variable dataView cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to a final variable and only final variables can be referenced from inside the enclosed type. You can however mutate final variables from inside the enclosed type.

If the `DataView` is not immediately available you may need a blocking queue which will block until it becomes available:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue; 

final BlockingQueue<DataView> dataViews = new ArrayBlockingQueue<DataView>();
Form<?> form2 = new Form<Void>("form2") {
   @Override
   protected void onSubmit() {
      ...
      dataViews.offer(new DataView("listview", new ListDataProvider(list)));
      ...
   }
};
//form is submitted in a different thread somewhere between here and add
...
add(dataViews.take());
```

Now it is impossible to tell from the context you gave us but the simplest solution, which doesn't require any final variables, would be to just call `add(dataView)` inside submit like so:

```
Form<?> form2 = new Form<Void>("form2") {
   @Override
   protected void onSubmit() {
      ...
      DataView dataView = new DataView("listview", new ListDataProvider(list));
      add(dataView); 
      ...
   }
};
```

Comment: then on line **add(dataViews);** occur an error: **The method add(Component...) in the type MarkupContainer is not applicable for the arguments (List<DataView>)**

Comment: That is because the `add()` method expects a `DataView` not a `List`. But you also need to make sure that the `submit` method executes and `dataView` is added to the list before you call `add()` at the end. You may even need `java.util.concurrent.Future`.