# Where is the local final variable in method stored (Stack/Heap)?

Tags: java, oop, memory, final

I know that method variables are stored on stack of the memory but slightly confused over `final`. I had browsed many links like [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/245252/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Method-Final-variable-stored-stack) could not get proper understanding? below is the example of `inner class` in which `final` variables are accessed and local `non-final` variables are not as they are stored in `stack`

```
class Employee {
public void getAddress(){
final int location = 13; 
int notFinalVar = 13;   
    class Address {
       System.out.println (location); 
       System.out.println (notFinalVar); // compiler error
    }
}
```

**Update**: Just now came to know about hidden fields called `synthetic field`( `inner class heap memory area`) in which copy of final variables are stored so does it finally means that final variables are stored in finally `Stack memory Area`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reading through some answers of SO and articles, My understanding is :

The answer is **stack**. All local variable (final or not) stored into the stack and go out of scope when the method execution is over.

But about final variable JVM take these as a constant as they will not change after initiated . And when a inner class try to access them compiler create a copy of that variable (not that variable it self) into the heap and create a synthetic field inside the inner class so even when the method execution is over
it is accessible because the inner class has it own copy.

`so does it finally means that final variables are stored in finally Stack memory Area?`

**final variable also stored in stack but the copy that variable which a inner class have stored in heap.**

---

**synthetic field** are filed which actually doesn't exist in the source code but compiler create   those fields in some inner classes to make those field accessible. In simple word hidden field.

References :

[How does marking a variable as final allow inner classes to access them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025907/how-does-marking-a-variable-as-final-allow-inner-classes-to-access-them)

[Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen/)

[Mystery of Accessibility in Local Inner Classes](http://techtracer.com/2008/04/14/mystery-of-accessibility-in-local-inner-classes/)

Comment: Yes: it's because of this copy that java requires you to declare these variables as final.

Comment: can you elaborate over  ` synthetic synthetic field ` in innner class

Comment: `synthetic synthetic field` was a typo it is `synthetic field`. I updated my answer @BhargavModi

Comment: Note : In java-8.. A field can be *effectively final* and not *explicitly final*.

Comment: @TheLostMind whats the difference between those two? it will be helpful if you elaborate or post a answer

Comment: @BhargavModi - Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938095/difference-between-final-and-effectively-final)