# Understanding Java's approximation to "closures"

Tags: java, closures

So, here's what I understand: Java doesn't support closures, so it sort of copies the variables from the containing scope into the nested scope, so they are available later. Because this is a copy, there is no way to synchronize the original and the copy, and the variable is forced to be final so the developer cannot change it and expect it to be updated. This understanding is partly taken form these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

And that brings us to this code working:

```
public class SimpleClosure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleClosure().doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        final int number = 3;

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(number));
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

So, great. Now, the thing is, a final modifier only prevents me from changing the object that the variable points to, but I can change the object without problems. If a "copy" was made, then changes to the object contents should not be reflected. The question, therefore is, why does the following code work?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StretchingClosure {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StretchingClosure().doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("animal", "cat");

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(map.get("animal")); // Outputs dog See (1)
            }
        }.start();
        map.put("animal", "dog");
    }
}
```

Needless to say, I'm missing something, or I'm oversimplyfying the way the compiler handles these cases. Could anyone please enlighten me?

(1): as pointed out by @trashgod, the output is true most of the time on most of the platforms, but it's not guaranteed due to the lack of synchronization. This is good enough for the example, but bad practice in general.

Comment: "Java doesn't support closures" What do you mean "closures"? Anything that has access to variables in the surrounding scope is a "closure". Whether it captures variables by value or by reference, or whether those variables are assignable, are separate issues.

Comment: @newacct well, I thought it was widely agreed that Java doesn't support closures, but just an approximation to them using anonymous classes. Variables referenced within the inner class must be specifically marked (with `final`) and their values are not kept up to date in and outside the block (only the content, but not the reference can be changed. This is also implicit to the way java handles variables). [This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04247/index.html) might explain it better than me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse the variable with the object: the **reference** from the local variable is indeed copied, but it still refers to the same object, in your case the map. There is a widely known idiom to work around the `final` restriction, involving arrays:

```
final int[] x = {1};
... use in an anonymous instance...
System.out.println(x[0]);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. This makes sense now. As to the idiom, I understand you're changing the value of x in the anonymous instance, and then it's no longer 1 after it, right? Neat trick (yet very wrong ;)

Comment: Yes, you use `x[0]` as you would otherwise use just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Java does the same thing there as it does with regular method parameters:

Method parameters are passed by reference value, so while you cannot change the object itself, if it is mutable and provides ways of mutating its inner state, you can change that state. You cannot change a string, but you can change the items inside a collection, for example.

The reference is passed by value = the reference is copied. The object itself isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The comment `// Outputs dog` is misleading in the sense that it's only true most of the time on most platforms. One second is plenty of time to update the `Map` on the initial thread, but nothing guarantees *visibility* of the updated value in the anonymous thread unless access to the shared data is correctly synchronized. See [*Memory Consistency Properties*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) for a nice summary of relevant features in `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: Fair enough :) I was only making a quick example, but being strict, you're right. I'm adding it to the question as a note, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes do not get copies of variables, but rather copies of references to the objects, that's why after 1s you get the "right" value which was changed outside the anonymous class.

Comment: They do get copies. At runtime, the value is stored in a compiler-generated member variable of the anonymous class. That don't mean that a reference copy wouldn't still point to the actual object.

Comment: I think the inner behaviour is not really important, the point is that in the inner class it is as if we have a reference that can't be reassigned, but the object in itself can be modified (and modifications will be available outside of the inner class). But thanks for the precision though, it's useful for my personal knowledge :)

Comment: @eis well, it cannot be copied, since a copy of the map would point to the String "cat" instead of "dog"

Comment: He means the reference is copied, not the object being referenced. The two references point to the same object.