# Change Variable from the inside of a ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

Is it possible to change a variable from inside of a `ActionListener`?

I mean somthing like this:

```
    boolean test = false;

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            test = true;
        }
    });
```

I want to change `test` to true when someone presses the button.

Comment: `white` is `boolean` variable here?

Comment: I am totally surprised how you managed to call `addActionListener` method on a boolean `white`

Comment: Is this JavaScript? Not Java? Please update tags in that case.

Comment: No i mistyped it. The boolean shouldn´t be the ActionListener. I made this as an example and forget to change it.

Comment: @Roger Gustavsson, even if it was javascript one cannot call methods on a boolean value and moreover the code syntax and methods are from Java.

Comment: And no its not JavaScript

Comment: Can you edit back your question @Alexander

Comment: Any exception while doing like this?

Comment: Local variable vari defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final. Thats the error that Eclips gets. And the first Variable gets the Error: The value of the local variable vari is not used

Comment: so `vari` is declared inside a method. Try to declare it inside a class but outside of any method.

Comment: Yea is that the mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Java's approximation to "closures"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522363/understanding-javas-approximation-to-closures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps you but if you are using a action listener I'm guessing you are working with javas swing api. In that case you are maybe extending a class like `JFrame` or something like that so you could use this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private boolean booleanToChange = false;

    private JButton exampleButton;

    public MyFrame() {
        exampleButton = new JButton();
        exampleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                //Access a member in anonymous class
                MyFrame.this.booleanToChange = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) the explanation why it has to be final :) hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you wanted??

```
private boolean booly = true; 

private class WinkAction implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        if (booly){
            booly = false; 
        }else {
            booly = true;
            repaint( );         
        }   
    }
}
```