# How can I change the value of a variable from inside an ActionListener in Java?

Tags: java

```
    int test;

b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b){
        test = 1;
    }
});
```

How could I use this action listener to change test to 1 I know the code above doesn't work but what can I do?

Comment: Okay I just realized that it has void in the action Listener so that makes sense.

Comment: What return type has to do with variable visibility?

Comment: [Change Variable from the inside of a ActionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464541/change-variable-from-the-inside-of-a-actionlistener) is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you simply cannot do that.

Assuming that `test` is a local variable, the callback method is not permitted to change it.

Why?

Because by the time that the callback is called, the method that declared the `test` variable may have returned, meaning that the variable no longer exists.  (The compiler complain that `test` should be read only in the listener method ... I think.)

---

Lets put this into a (hypothetical) context:

```
public class MyClass {
    Button b = ...

    public void myMethod() {
        int test = 0;

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b){
                test = 1;   // COMPILATION ERROR
            }
        });

        System.out.println("test is " + test);
    }
}
```

The intention here is to print "test is 1" when the button is clicked.

But this won't work.  The problem is that `addActionListener` adds the listener method and returns immediately.  The next thing that happens is that `myMethod` will try to print `test`.  Even if this was legal Java (it isn't!) the value printed would be `0` ... not `1`.

We could "fix" the compilation error by declaring `test` as an instance variable rather than a local variable.

```
public class MyClass {
    Button b = ...
    int test = 0;

    public void myMethod() {

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b){
                test = 1;   // OK now ...
            }
        });

        System.out.println("test is " + test);
    }
}
```

But the code still doesn't do what we want.  The `test` variable will be printed too soon.

The thing you need to understand is that callbacks always happen later.  If you want to see the change to `test` at the point of the `println`, then callbacks (listeners) are not the right way to implement things.

---

Summary: you have both a compilation error AND a conceptual problem in your example code.

Comment: My intention is not to print it out its just to store it for later so if this changes it at the click of a button then it works because the only time I would use it would be at the click of another button so the instance variable should work.

Comment: Then your mistake is storing it in a local variable.  Because the local variable won't be there "later".

Comment: Yeah I realized that and changing it to an instance variable worked perfectly well for what I'm doing so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable unless they are final because this is the way Java manages closures.

```
private final MyClass test = new MyClass();

b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b){
        test.setMyInt(1);
    }
});

public class MyClass{
    int myInt;
    // getter/setter
}
```

Comment: It can just be a local variable. That or just `myInt` directly as a field of the enclosing class.