# non-final variable inside an inner class

Tags: java, android

I try to create dynamically a ImageView and I want to pass this imageView as a parameter to a method into the listener.

```
            ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this);

            imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                        detectLocationAndShowPopUp(imageView1);
                        return true;
                    }
                })
```

But I'm taking the following error:
                                                                                                                                     Cannot refer to a non-final variable imageView1 inside an inner class defined in a different method.

I don't want to declare the imageView as final. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a copy of imageView1 and then use the copy inside the listener:

```
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this);
final ImageView imageView2 = imageView1;

imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        detectLocationAndShowPopUp(imageView2);
        return true;
    }
});
```

After Sam's comment I change my code to:

```
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this);

imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        detectLocationAndShowPopUp((ImageView) view);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great general answer. But for those that don't know Android, `arg0` is a reference to `imageView1` simply cast it to an ImageView if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is Android, `arg0` will be your image when you touch it. Use:

```
detectLocationAndShowPopUp((ImageView) arg0);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I improved your answer a little by adding a code sample and using the markup tools. I also gave you an upvote since this answer is correct.  You can improve your answer again with some of the advice in [ask] by clicking "[edit]".

Comment: Whoops! I meant to like to [answer]... :)

Answer (score 2):

Create `ImageView imageView1` as a global class variable.

And initialize it inside the function as you are doing, without declaring it again.

Something like

```
MyClass extends ...
{
....
ImageView imageView1;
.
.
.
.
.
myFucntion()
{
imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this);
}

}
```

Comment: You beat me to the example, yes, this is how it should be done

Answer (score 2):

Don't define the `ImageView` in a method. Make it a member variable declared under your class definition

Answer (score 2):

Your are using an anonymous class and not an inner class (like the title says). In anonymous classes you can only refer to `final` "variables".

If you don't want to add `final` to `imageView` and dont want to use another final variable you can use an inner class:

```
public class YourActivity extends ... {
  public void yourMethod() {
    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this);
    imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new MyListener(imageView1));
  }

  private class MyListener extends OnTouchListener {
    private ImageView imageView;

    public MyListener(ImageView iv) {
      this.imageView = iv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
     detectLocationAndShowPopUp(imageView);
     return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Idea one**: Use another final variable.

```
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this);
final ImageView finalImageView = imageView1;
imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    detectLocationAndShowPopUp(finalImageView);
    return true;
  }
})
```

**Idea two**: Use an anonymous subclass of ImageView, then use the `ImageView.this` reference.

```
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(LookActivity.this) {{
  setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
      detectLocationAndShowPopUp(ImageView.this);
      return true;
    }
}};
```