# why final variable is used in inner classes in java

Tags: java

I am asking this , because final & non-final have same scope , so why VARIABLE are added as 
final variable in java .. & what is the affect of adding some variable as final , when it is only accessed under some scope .

```
public void game()
{
    final String str = "a" ;
        //String str ="a" ;

    class hollow 
    {
        public void game ()
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you clarify your question!

Comment: See [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1299837/851811), or [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4732544/851811).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final and inner classes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_variables

> When an anonymous inner class is defined within the body of a method,
>   all variables declared final in the scope of that method are
>   accessible from within the inner class. Once it has been assigned, the
>   value of the final variable cannot change. This allows the Java
>   compiler to "capture" the value of the variable at run-time and store
>   a copy as a field in the inner class. Once the outer method has
>   terminated and its stack frame has been removed, the original variable
>   is gone but the inner class's private copy persists in the class's own
>   memory.