# Change local variables android onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I need to set the return value of this method to be the item selected in a Single Choice Dialog...

However, i cannot set the value of retVal because it apparently needs to be final (therefore cannot be changed)

Is there any way to do this without using global variables?

```
private String getSaleType()
{
    String retVal = "";
    final String[] TYPES = {"Cash Sale", "Sales Order"};
    AlertDialog.Builder choose = null;

    try
    {
        choose = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        choose.setIcon(R.drawable.firstdroidicon);
        choose.setTitle("Sale Type");
        choose.setMessage("Type Of Sale?");
        choose.setSingleChoiceItems(TYPES, currentItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Log.i("Selected", TYPES[which]);
            }
        });
        choose.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                retVal = TYPES[which];
            }
        });

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        messageBox("getSaleType", e.getMessage());
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: declare the variable as a class member

Comment: @Raghunandan I would like to avoid doing this...i dont like having loads of variables declared at the top of the class. Can you explain why retVal has to be final?

Comment: i don't know any other way other than what i have suggested. bcoz you have you have inner class and a method inside it. so it should be final

Comment: Can't this be done with `String retVal1 = ""; final String retVal = "";` and then before the return do `retVal1 = retVal;` and return `retVal1`. Anyway what's the problem with `final` in this case, you're not using this variable more than once and after that you just return it?

Comment: @LouisEvans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen. here's an explanation on the topic

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

You can find that in [JLS # chapter 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared final.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in an inner class must be definitely assigned (§16) before the body of the inner class.