# SharedPreferences - Save number of button clicks

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm working on a simple 'Click Countdown' application, which basically has an imagebutton
function. When pressed it displays the number of clicks from 10 to 9, 8, 7,... to 0.
I have a problem, when I close the application the number of clicks starts again from
10. I wrote somethink, but it doesn´t work and say: *Cannot refer to a non-final variable prefsEditor inside an inner class defined in a different method.*-(prefsEditor) Can someone help me please?

This is the code I have so far. I there mistake?

```
package com.example.testapp;

import com.example.testapp.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton button1;
    TextView textView1;
    int counter = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

        ImageButton imageButton;
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {



            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (counter >= 1) {
                    counter--;
                    textView1.setText("" + counter);

                    prefsEditor.putInt("counter", counter);
                    prefsEditor.commit();

                } else if (counter == 0){
                    button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
                    counter--;

                    prefsEditor.putInt("counter", counter);
                    prefsEditor.commit();


                }


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

make prefsEditor final

```
final SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
```