# why I cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method?

Tags: java, inner-classes, final

Why I cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method?
I've seen topics about this and in most of them people say that your component should be final and ... . But nobody says why?!! and I don't know what's the philosophy behind this limitation.
What makes me confused more is that the following code is erroneous :

```
JButton removeJBtn = new JButton("Remove");
    JButton addJBtn = new JButton("Add");
    //...
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            removeJBtn.disable();//Error here,Cannot ...


        }
    });
```

while if I define

```
 JButton removeJBtn
```

as a member field (in the body of the class,not the method) it's not required to be defined as final!

I'll really appreciate any logical answer to this daily limit that I (and probably many others) always face.

---

Dear users that marked this question as a duplicate, please at least give a reference to the original question  (that has been answered for sure!), there is a link in added above my question that I read it throughly but it's full of contradictions, some one (with 88 up votes) says java captures the value of final variables and it's completely rejected by a comment (with 16 votes) below it.

Comment: see why [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Comment: Note: Inner classes and anonymous classes are a totally different thing!

Comment: @Smutje: Would you please explain more?

Comment: Okay, should have taken more time: Anonymous classes are a special kind of inner class. For more information, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 9):

The local variables of the method live on the stack, and exist only for
the lifetime of the method. You already know that the scope of a local variable is
limited to the method the variable is declared in. When the method ends, the stack
frame is blown away and the variable is history. But even after the method
completes, the inner class object created within it might still be alive on the heap if,
for example, a reference to it was passed into some other code and then stored in an
instance variable. Because the local variables aren't guaranteed to be alive as long
as the method-local inner class object, the inner class object can't use them. Unless
the local variables are marked final!

**Source**: Kathy Sierra SCJP

Comment: So do you say the inner class (ActionListener here) may remains alive whilst removeJBtn has been destroyed? does marking it as final keeps it alive?

Comment: This isn't quite right.  See the comment thread on the accepted answer  here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen.  Also, there's a good discussion of variable capture by value here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Local_classes_.28Java.29.

Answer (score 1):

Because a normal variable only resides on the stack (the pointer to the object in your case). Since the inner class can (and usually does) live longer than the defining method, the variable would not be present anymore.

By making the variable final, the compiler can create optimizations (in this case: include the final variable as "secret" member in the inner class. This would not be valid, if the variable were not final, because it could change afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the other answers, you should keep in mind that anonymous classes are syntactic Java sugar to keep you from creating concrete classes and instantiating them every time you for example have to provide a button listener - if you want to do this (you can easily skip anonymous classes and replace them by concrete classes without a problem), you had to pass the values (here: the `removeJBtn`) into the objects by constructor to use them internally and you had created a new object explicitly, which lives on the heap and therefore longer then the method where you register the listeners.