# How to retrieve variable from inner class defined in different method?

Tags: java, inner-classes

So right now I have the following:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

int size;

public Panel()
{
    JButton newBut = new JButton();

    newBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            boolean validInput = false;
            while (!validInput)
            {
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please specify a number:");
                try{
                    size = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    validInput = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Invalid Input!", "ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

                if (input == null)
                {
                    validInput = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now as you can see from the code, I am trying to parse the input from the user as an integer, and then store that value inside my global variable "size". However, when I try to do this I get the error:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

Setting size to `final` is not an option for me, since I need `size` to be able to change each time the user inputs a new value. So I honestly have no idea how I'm supposed to retrieve the size variable from the inner method. Any help would be mightily appreciated.

Comment: hmm, I like these types of bugs. Thanks actually I need to brush up on this. The whole static vs. non-static  & final vs non-final. access privileges & such . It's very very important to grok it

Comment: a good source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen?rq=1

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code compiles for me. Java 1.7.0. The error message applies to a method-local variable, not a class member. Clearly this isn't the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @EJP is right....I have also tried in Java 8 using netbeans...for me it is working perfectly...but if still you get problem then implement `ActionListener` to your class and then make a separate method for this...here is the code....

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    int size;

    public Panel()
    {
        JButton newBut = new JButton("Button");  //give some name just to check..
        newBut.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(newBut);  //you have not added your button to the Panel..so I did it
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  //same method just outside the inner class
        boolean validInput = false;   //all the functionality is same as your nothing is changed
        while (!validInput)
        {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please specify a number:");
            try{
                size = Integer.parseInt(input);
                validInput = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Invalid Input!", "ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            if (input == null)
            {
                validInput = true;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I think it may help you...

Answer (score -1):

You **could** cheat and use an `AtomicInteger` or similar, and call its `set(int)` method. But I would instead reconsider your design -- *why* are you trying to stash this value in a global anyways?

Also, what's with the floating

```
if (input == null)
{
    validInput = true;
}
```

block?

Comment: Yes you can. I do it all the time. What you can't do is set a method-local variable in the enclosing method. That doesn't appear in this question.

Comment: D'oh, you're right -- I misread the OP's question based on the quoted compiler message.