# Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException when trying to make links clickable in JTable

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

The aim is to make the link clickable in jtable so that when user clicks on the link the desired page gets opened in the browser. One of the items fetched from database is link and my attempt is to make it active and clickable. I get the error as

```
Unhandled exception type URISyntaxException
```

For the line in my code:

```
final URI uri = new URI("http://www.roseindia.net");
```

And even if i put it in try catch block, the error doesn't seem to resolve. Rather on surrounding in a try-catch block, I get the error as

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable uri inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

So what could be the possible solution and fix?

```
 public  class JTableButtonMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        private final JTable table;

        public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table)
        {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            counter=0;
        //  System.out.println("***************************************************************");
            System.out.println("counter value="+counter++);
            //System.out.println("/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
            int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int row    = e.getY()/table.getRowHeight(); 

            if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >= 0) {
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
              //  System.out.println("row clicked="+row);
                //System.out.println("column clicked="+column);
                System.out.println("object value="+value);
                System.out.println(".............................................................");
              /* public void getsecname(String s)
                {
                    String ss=s;
                }*/
                if(table.getValueAt(row, 4)!=null)
                {
                    Object ob = table.getValueAt(row, 4);
                    String link_string=ob.toString();
                    // final URI uri = null;
                    // URI uri;
                     try{
                            final URI uri = new URI("http://www.roseindia.net");
                        } 
                     catch (URISyntaxException e1)
                     {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    System.out.println(".....................");
                      ((AbstractButton) ob).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                                            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                                            try {
                                                    desktop.browse(uri);
                                                  //  button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

                                                   // desktop.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                            }
                                    } else {
                                    }
                            }


                    });


                }

              //  String link_string=ob.toString();
            //ob.setClickable(true);

                if(value==null)
                {
                    Object v=table.getValueAt(row, 1);
                    //System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

                     s = v.toString();


                       jmenu_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                            jmenu_frame.setContentPane(new ListModelExample(s));
                            jmenu_frame.setSize(260, 200);

                     jmenu_frame.setVisible(true);

                     jmenu_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                     //it ends here
                }
                if (value instanceof JButton) {
                    ((JButton)value).doClick();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: *`final URI uri = new URI("http://www.roseindia.net");`* That should throw a `CrappyCodeSiteException`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use non-final variable inside your inner class. [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen).

```
if(table.getValueAt(row, 4)!=null)
    {
        Object ob = table.getValueAt(row, 4);
        String link_string=ob.toString();

        try {
            final URI uri = new URI("http://www.roseindia.net");
            System.out.println(".....................");

            ((AbstractButton) ob).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                        try {
                            desktop.browse(uri);
                            //button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                            // desktop.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is telling you is that you need a `try catch` block to handle a `URISyntaxException`:

```
final URI;
try{
    uri = new URI("http://www.roseindia.net");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To solve `uri cannot be resolved to a variable` You could instead of using `try catch`, add a `throws URISyntaxException` to the method in which `uri` is declared. But I do not think that is a good practice. Maybe it works in your case.

Comment: yes i know but on doing so i get the second error as mentioned above. What could be the possible fix ?

Comment: To solve `Cannot refer to a non-final variable uri inside an inner class defined in a different method` you need to declare your variable as `final`, and you did, it should not show that error now.

Comment: I did what u suggested and now it gives the error as uri cannot be resolved to a variable at line  desktop.browse(uri); in my code

Comment: That is because if the try fails, the variable would not bee accesible  in the rest of your code. In what inner class are you using `uri`?

Comment: I've now included my full code with class. Kindly have a look and let me know the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54446/discussion-between-user3608233-and-algui91).