# java program not compiling, issues with scope and lifetime of variables

Tags: java

I am new to java. Could anyone explain why the following program not working? Thanks.

```
class AnonymousInnerClassInMethod
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int local = 1;

        Comparable compare = new Comparable ()
        {
            public int compareTo(Object value)
            {
                return (Integer)value - local;
            }
        };
        System.out.println(compare.compareTo(5)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `final int local = 1;` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen).

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in future. Look at the preview of your post before you submit it, and ask yourself whether that's how *you'd* want to read it if you were trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to declare `local` as `final`:

```
final int local = 1;
```

(More information about this matter on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen), as suggested by **sp00m**).

Or define it as a `static` field of your class:

```
class AnonymousInnerClassInMethod {
    private static int local = 1;
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem: You can't declare a `public static void main(String[] args)` inside a nested class, unless you mark that class as `static` as well.

Second problem: The anonymous constructor you use to define the compare's `compareTo` method cannot access the non-final variable `local`. This is an error, because the variable might change during/after construction of the object. Hence, if you mark it as final, it is ensured that the variable cannot change.