# Why is the final keyword used profusely inside of methods even though it's completely fine to not define them final

Tags: java, final

I asked a collegue why he used final keyword for the assignment in this method and his response was, "Why not?". I don't see the benefit of putting final here. Or often times, I see it in class definitions as well.

```
protected void sendIndexWorkflowRequest(Status status)
{

    final long contextId = status.getAppContextId();
    PrepareIndexPostData preparePostData = new PrepareIndexPostData.Builder(contextId).build();

    searchIndexService.activateAggsIndex(preparePostData);
}
```

Comment: It's more explicit that the variable is never changed. This (case) is a matter of opinion, it is not required by the language.

Comment: apart from exceptional cases, if you need to use `final` on a local variable to make it clear that it does not change, it is very likely that your method is too long...

Comment: I'd consider it as a safety in messy methods where the reference might be re-assigned by mistake. Otherwise, pretty pointless.

Comment: So I see this as more of a documentation than anything else!

Comment: Usually for readability, but could be a needed constraint (like it's used twice but must have same value both times).

Comment: It is simple good practice to do so. The same to encapsulate members with private and access only thru getter/setter, catch Exception properly, etc, etc. All that stuff we know we should do and we don't.

Comment: Also `final` is usually quite important on multi-threading cases, to ensure that a variable will not change and thus all threads will see the same value.

Comment: @m0skit0 That's not relevant for local variables.

Comment: Basically, the language would have been better if `final` was the default and a special modifier was needed on a mutable variable. Most local variables are effectively final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's asserting that that variable *mustn't change* within the method. It's essentially a coding safety check. i.e. the compiler will raise an error if the variable is re-assigned to (most likely accidentally) and is often regarded as a good practise.

You may see something similar with method parameters e.g.

```
public void method(final Object a) {
  // ...
}
```

which asserts that the `Object 'a'` reference shouldn't change within the method. You may want to change it at some stage (in which case remove the `final`) but leaving it as `final` whilst you don't need it to be mutable may protect you against coding errors.

Note that `final` variables will be required if you're [referencing such variables within an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen) (now not a requirement with Java 8, which can determine non-final variables as being *effectively final*)

Comment: But in the end it is up to whoever comes later to decide whether it is final or not. So, I dont see the point in defining as final a variable used only once.

Comment: You can always refactor and make mutable later, yes. But that's a concious decision. If it isn't then the final will protect you (hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice so you dont end up reusing local variable and would be helpful in future to refactor such method.