# JButton listener calling method in class gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

New to java here, and I am attempting my first project with GUI. I have a GameConsole class that contains gamePlay() and userTurn(). I have a ButtonListener class that constructs the button with an actionListener that calls userTurn(). However, every time that the button is pressed, I get a `NullPointerException`. Why is this happening and what do I do to fix it?

Relevant code:

```
public static final void main (String[] args){
    GameConsole game = new GameConsole();
    game.gamePlay();
}

public class GameConsole {
    public Player user;
    public Player dealer;
    public Deck playingDeck;
    ValidateInput validate = new ValidateInput();

public void gamePlay(){
    //get info from user
    user.addToHand(playingDeck.getTopCard());
    dealer.addToHand(playingDeck.getTopCard());
    user.addToHand(playingDeck.getTopCard());
    dealer.addToHand(playingDeck.getTopCard());

    userTurn();
}

public void userTurn(){
    boolean turn = true;
    do{   //the code breaks at this point. On the first round of gameplay I get the exception pasted
          //below. The second round (after the button is pressed) I get an 
          //Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0      bringing me back here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The cards you were dealt are: \n" + user.printHand());

        if(user.sumOfHand() == 21){  //no need to continue if user has 21
            System.out.println("You win this round.");
            break;
        } else if (user.sumOfHand() > 21){
            System.out.println("You have busted. You lose this round.");
            break;
        }


        String HSInput = null;
        for(int x = 0; x < 1;){
        HSInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nThe dealer is showing a " + dealer.getTopCard()
                + "\nYou are currently at " + user.sumOfHand()
                + "\n\nWhat would you like to do?\nHit (H) or Stay (S)?");
        if(validate.containDesiredString(HSInput, "HhSs")) //only accept h and s either caps
            x++;
        }


        if(HSInput.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){  //if the user wants to stay
            user.addToHand(playingDeck.getTopCard()); //deal new card then repeat loop
        } 
        else {
            turn = false;
            }
    } while (turn == true);
}
```

And the ButtonListener class...

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    JButton newRoundButton;

    public ButtonListener(JPanel endGamePanel){

        newRoundButton = new JButton("Start another round");
        newRoundButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 50));
        endGamePanel.add(newRoundButton);
        newRoundButton.addActionListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
        if(e.getSource() == newRoundButton){
            System.out.println("Hi there for a new round");
                     //I know that this method is entered into because this line will print
            GameConsole game = new GameConsole();
            game.userTurn();
        }
    }
```

I am desperately lost and have been going in circles for the last 2 days. Right now the program won't even enter the userTurn(). I have no idea what I did because a couple hours ago that wasn't a problem. Either way, my ultimate problem is that I can't get the ButtonListener to call the userTurn() class. Why am I now getting a `NullPointerException` for the userTurn() and what can I do to make the ActionListener call the userTurn() without giving a `NullPointerException`?

-Hopelessly Lost... ANY help is appreciated!

EDIT: Stack Trace
Exception in thread "main" jav

```
a.lang.NullPointerException
    at blackjackControls.GameConsole.userTurn(GameConsole.java:180)
    at blackjackControls.GameConsole.gamePlay(GameConsole.java:119)
    at blackjackControls.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

since it is no longer going into the userTurn() I can't post the trace for that. It did state that it was a thread in the AWT

ButtonListener class has been combined with existing ResultPane class. Full code is:

```
public class ResultPanel extends JFrame {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Blackjack Game");
    JPanel endGamePanel = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon image;
    JLabel lbl;
    JButton newRoundButton;
    JButton endButton;

    public ResultPanel(){

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().add(endGamePanel);   //add the panel to the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       

        JButton newRoundButton= new JButton("Start another round");
        newRoundButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 50));
//      newRoundButton.addActionListener();
        newRoundButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println("Hi there for a new round");
                GameConsole game = new GameConsole();
                game.userTurn();
            }
        });


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void winGame(){
        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("win.jpg"));
        lbl = new JLabel (image);
        endGamePanel.add(lbl);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: On which specific line is the NPE? Are you sure you have assigned values to user, dealer, and playingDeck?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: My "guess" is, `user` is `null`...

Comment: *"New to java here, and I am attempting my first project with GUI."*  A programmer should be familiar with how to solve an NPE *before* they attempt to make a GUI!  See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: Stack trace is posted and I have verified that user is not null. I have printed data contained in the object before the spot in which the program breaks. right not it is breaking in the line with the first JOptionPane in userTurn()

Comment: `at blackjackControls.GameConsole.userTurn(GameConsole.java:180)`  We cannot tell which is line `180`, but.. For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) with a stack trace for the short complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you create a new `GameConsole` object in your main, so I assume this is the object the whole game is played on. If this is the case, why does your button create a new `GameConsole` object? I assume you're getting a `NullPointerException` because your button calls the `userTurn()` method on a new `GameConsole` object that doesn't have a User object yet, so `user.sumOfHand()` for example would throw the exception.

Your button should call the `userTurn` method on the `GameConsole` object you created in your main, not on a new one.

Code Suggestion:

```
JButton newRoundButton= new JButton("Start another round");
newRoundButton.setPreferedSize(new Dimension(150, 50));
newRoundButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hi there for a new round");
        game.userTurn();
    }
});
endGamePanel.add(newRoundButton);
```

This is assuming that whatever class builds your panel knows about your `GameConsole` object. If this class is the `GameConsole` object itself, just remove `game.` If an object of that class is created in your `GameConsole` object, just pass your `GameConsole` object to that class with a parameter `GameConsole game` in that classes constructor and, if needed make it a field in that class. To pass your `GameConsole` object from that object, pass `this`.

Comment: Yes, the whole game is played on GameConsole. How would I use the game object created in main? I keep getting static errors.

Comment: You could make `GameConsole game` a parameter of your `ButtonListener` construcor and make a field `GameConsole game` in the `ButtonListener` class. Then initialize the field in the constructor. Now you can call `game.userTurn()` inside the `ButtonListener` class without having to create a new `GameConsole` object.

Comment: The way it is designed, ButtonListener is indirectly called from Game Console. So I would have to go from main() to userTurn() which constructs my ResultPanel class which constructs ButtonListener within that constructor. When I designed it, it all made logical sense, but is passing a paramenter that far down the line good practice? Is there a more direct way? I understand I left that part out of the original information, but this is a rather large program (for what I am used to working with).

Comment: I usually pass my controller to my UI classes (frames, panels) and as far as I can tell this is a good way to relay information to your UI. One thing I don't understand though is why you are making your buttons ActionListener a seperate class. I would suggest to just add your button directly to your panel. I've updated my original answer with the code.

Comment: Thank you for being so thorough. I split up the button into another class because I had two buttons (in the same buttonListener class) and I saw a couple tutorials in which the same was done. It made sense to me because a button is its own object with its own properties/actions. I am now getting the same Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0". This occurs at the same place where I am still getting the first NullPointerException. I updated the code to show you exactly where. Thanks so much!

Comment: Okay, you're still creaing a new `GameConsole` object in your buttons ActionListener. Remove `GameConsole game = new GameConsole();` because **this creates a new game** and you said that the whole game is played on one `GameConsole` object. Change your `ResultPanel`'s constructor to `public ResultPanel(GameConsole game)` and pass your `GameConsole` object to the panel when calling the constructor. That way your button can call the `userTurn()` method on your original `GameConsole` object and as far as I can tell that's what you desire.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the comment come in last night. I did that now, but in main() since game is in main, I now am getting "cannot refer to a non-final variable game inside and inner class defined in a different manner". I feel like I am going in circles and I know I am missing a huge concept.

Comment: Try declaring your `ResultPanel`'s `GameConsole` field final. See [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen) for more information on that error.

Comment: I ended up having to backtrack and take out the final. See the answer solution I posted. You still helped HUGELY. It makes a ton more sense to have the window called in main()

Comment: No problem. If my answer has helped you, please consider accepting it. Also see [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inizialise your objects.

```
 public class GameConsole {
    public Player user = new Player();
    public Player dealer = new Player();
    public Deck playingDeck = new Deck();
```

This is how you could do it

Comment: I initialized in the gamePlay() method. I declared on the class level because I wanted to make them available to both methods.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at over 1100 lines of code, I user was null because I declared it again in gamePlay() which made it a local variable. ONE WORD stumped me for 3 days. Argh!