# Adding ActionListeners to array of buttons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, chess

I'm trying to write my first Swing app, it is a simple chess engine in Java. I've made a grid of JButtons to represent squares.  Looks ok, but I've come across a problem when trying to add ActionListeners to each square. I want to get squares co-ordinates and print it to console when its clicked. This is what I tried(I guess I don't really understand how ActionListeners work):

```
// chessBoardSquares[][] is an 8x8 array of Jbuttons

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

            chessBoardSquares[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    System.out.println("x: "+i+"y: "+j);

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this not work? Does it compile? Run? Misbehave? Throw an exception? Something else?

Comment: Ah, I see -- you need final variables that's it

Comment: Cannot refer to the non-final local variable i defined in an enclosing scope 
Cannot refer to the non-final local variable j defined in an enclosing scope

Comment: I guessed as much. See answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use either fields or final local variables inside an anonymous inner class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        final int finalJ = j;

        chessBoardSquares[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("x: " + finalI +"y: " + finalJ);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Effectively final is enough, so `final` modifiers are optional.

Comment: @EasternDude: glad you've got it solved. For more details on the underpinnings of this, please check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1299837/522444) (which I found after answering this question).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually, it seems to be a new improvement for Java 8. So if you're having an older version, it won't compile.

Comment: 1+, @Bubletan, this code works fine for me using JDK7.

Comment: @camickr Yes, this works with JDK7. The one in my answer shouldn't, as far as I'm right.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Java 8, you can have use both final and effectively final variables inside anonymous classes (or lambda expressions). An effectively final variable is not declared as `final`, but its value is never changed.

Your code could be written like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

        int finalI = i; // no final modifier
        int finalJ = j;

        chessBoardSquares[i][j].addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("x: " + finalI + "y: " + finalJ);
        });
    }
}
```