# Cannot refer to the non-final local variable defined in an enclosing scope

Tags: java, scope, final

So I'm getting the following error in eclipse and I am not understanding what is the problem:

ERROR:

`Cannot refer to the non-final local variable minActiveDutyCycles defined in an enclosing scope`

The code `minActiveDutyCycles[i++];` on line B is underlined with red

for code:

```
    double[] minActiveDutyCycles = c.getMinActiveDutyCycles(); // LINE A <==== WHY DOES THIS VARIABLE NEED TO BE FINAL for code at LINE B???

    ArrayUtils.setIndexesTo(boostInterim, ArrayUtils.where(activeDutyCycles, new Condition.Adapter<Object>() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override public boolean eval(double d) { return d > minActiveDutyCycles[i++]; } // LINE B
    }), 1.0d);
```

Comment: Do you know what a final variable is? Do you know what a non-final variable is?

Comment: It's because Java (pre 8, at least) doesn't support true closures. More info in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen).