# Get Item from Listview in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have listview in my fragment and i'm trying to get item from my listview in my onclick event. But i got error that suggest me declared my list as final. When i try declare my list to final. I get another error "incompatible...".

this is my code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.announcement_fragment, container, false);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    ArrayList<Announcement> listAnnouncement = GetlistAnnouncement();
    ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_announcement);
    lv.setAdapter(new AnnouncementAdapter(listAnnouncement, getActivity()));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Announcement item =  lv.getItemAtPosition(i);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

i got error in this row

```
Announcement item =  lv.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

**Answer :**
change

```
Announcement item =  lv.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

to

```
Announcement item =  listAnnouncement.get(i);
```

or

```
Announcement item =  (Announcement)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i got error that suggest me declared my list as final

Your lv needs to be final cause it's used in a annonymous inner class.

[Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

> I get another error "incompatible...".

No need to use lv or make final. Change this

```
Announcement item =  lv.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

to

```
Announcement item =  (Announcement)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

`getItemAtPosition` returns an object requires casting

Docs:

```
public Object getItemAtPosition (int position)

Added in API level 1
Gets the data associated with the specified position in the list.

Parameters
position    Which data to get
Returns
The data associated with the specified position in the list
```

Comment: oh thanks, actually i was solved my problem by myself just now. But thanks for your answer. I'll vote :D