# How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get the "long term persistent download link" to files in our Firebase storage bucket.
I've changed the permissions of this to

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/project-xxx.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And my javacode looks like this:

```
private String niceLink (String date){
    String link;
    // Points to the root reference
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child("/" + date+ ".csv");
    link = dateRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();
    return link;
}
```

When I run this I get the uri link that looks something like
*com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh@xxx*

**Question 1.** Can I from this get the download link similar to: *https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-xxxx.appspot.com/o/20-5-2016.csv?alt=media&token=b5d45a7f-3ab7-4f9b-b661-3a2187adxxxx*

When trying to get the link above I changed the last row before my return, like this:

```
private String niceLink (String date){
    String link;
    // Points to the root reference
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child("/" + date+ ".csv");
    link = dateRef.getDownloadUrl().getResult().toString();
    return link;
}
```

But when doing this i get a 403 error, and the app crashing. The consol tells me this is bc user is not logged in /auth.
"Please sign in before asking for token"

**Question 2.** How do I fix this?

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) and this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose/) will help for sure.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation for getting a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url).

When you call `getDownloadUrl()`, the call is asynchronous and you must subscribe on a success callback to obtain the results:

```
// Calls the server to securely obtain an unguessable download Url
private void getUrlAsync (String date){
    // Points to the root reference
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child("/" + date+ ".csv");
    dateRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl) 
        {                
           //do something with downloadurl
        } 
    });
}
```

This will return a public unguessable download url. If you just uploaded a file, this public url will be in the success callback of the upload (you do not need to call another async method after you've uploaded).

However, if all you want is a `String` representation of the reference, you can just call `.toString()`

```
// Returns a Uri of the form gs://bucket/path that can be used
// in future calls to getReferenceFromUrl to perform additional
// actions
private String niceRefLink (String date){
    // Points to the root reference
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child("/" + date+ ".csv");
    return dateRef.toString();
}
```

Comment: Using the Async i seem too be getting an error with the .addSuccessListener (Cannot resolve method).
Furthermore, when I in the onSuccess method use something like link = downloadUrl.toString() it says it needs to be final.
Any further assistance would be awesome!

Comment: 1. Sorry, that should have been addOnSuccessListener (typo)
2. when you get an error "needs to be final" in java it means there is a closure issue.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen  fore more information.  Basically, the short answer is, define the "link" variable as a class member and it should be fine.

Comment: Worked like a sharm after some edits! Thx for the help!

Comment: On a side note, any "Unguessable download url", is still a public url that bypasses any access rule and can be accessed by anyone who happens to avail it.

Answer (score 9):

> //Firebase Storage - Easy to Working with uploads and downloads.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Signed in!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Signed in canceled!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    } else if(requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        // HERE I CALLED THAT METHOD
        uploadPhotoInFirebase(data);

    }
}

private void uploadPhotoInFirebase(@Nullable Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

    // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
    final StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotoStorageReference
                    .child(selectedImageUri
                    .getLastPathSegment());

    // Upload file to Firebase Storage
    photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    // Download file From Firebase Storage
                    photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadPhotoUrl) {
                            //Now play with downloadPhotoUrl
                            //Store data into Firebase Realtime Database
                            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage
                                    (null, mUsername, downloadPhotoUrl.toString());
                            mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**here i am uploading and getting the image url at the same time...**

```
           final StorageReference profileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            if (uriProfileImage != null) {

            profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                               // profileImageUrl taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(); //this is depreciated

                          //this is the new way to do it
                   profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                       String profileImageUrl=task.getResult().toString();
                                        Log.i("URL",profileImageUrl);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "aaa "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Comment: can you use this URL to show the Image to the user using the glide library?

Answer (score 3):

For me, I did my code in Kotlin and I had the same error "getDownload()". Here are both the dependencies that worked for me and the Kotlin code.

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.0'` firebase storage dependencies

This what I added and it worked for me in Kotlin. Storage() would come before Download()

```
profileImageUri = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Upload images to firestore and get it's download URL as below function:

```
  Future<String> uploadPic(File _image) async {

    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    var downloadURL = await(await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url =downloadURL.toString();

   return url;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
```

Recently getting url from upload task wasn't working so I tried this and worked for me on above dependency.
So inside where you use firebase upload method use this.
filepath is the reference of Firebase Stoarage.

```
filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: uri= "+ uri.toString());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

final   StorageReference fileupload=mStorageRef.child("Photos").child(fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
UploadTask uploadTask = fileupload.putFile(fileUri);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();

    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                Picasso.get().load(downloadUri.toString()).into(image);

            } else {
                 // Handle failures
            }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clean And Simple
private void putImageInStorage(StorageReference storageReference, Uri uri, final String key) {
        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this,
                new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, 
                                            new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage =
                                                new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                                                        task.getResult().toString());
                                        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).child(key)
                                                .setValue(friendlyMessage);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Image upload task was not successful.",
                                    task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The getDownloadUrl method was removed in firebase versions greater than 11.0.5
I recommend using version 11.0.2 that still uses this method.

Answer (score 0):

The getDownloadUrl method has now been depreciated in the new firebase update. Instead use the following method.
***taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString()***

Comment: Output is something like this: `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@ed93411`

Answer (score 0):

change the received **URI** to **URL**

```
 val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWith { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }


            spcaeRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                val downloadUri = task.result

                //URL
                val url = downloadUri!!.result

            } else {
                //handle failure here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also you can do as follows In latest Firebase_storage version nullsafe,**

```
//Import
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

Future<void> _downloadLink(firebase_storage.Reference ref) async {
    //Getting link make sure call await to make sure this function returned a value
    final link = await ref.getDownloadURL();

    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
      text: link,
    ));

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          'Success!\n Copied download URL to Clipboard!',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

firebase.storage().ref(`/users/${userUID}${path}/${newPostKey}`)
.getDownloadURL()
.then(url => object.imageUrl = url)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
taskSnapshot.metadata?.reference?.downloadUrl?.addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity, 
           OnCompleteListener<Uri?> { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    
                    Log.i("this is your url", task.result.toString())
                }
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void getDownloadUrl(){
        FirebaseStorage storage     = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference imageRef   = storageRef.child("image.jpg");
        imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                String profileimageurl =task.getResult().toString();
                Log.e("URL",profileimageurl);
                ShowPathTextView.setText(profileimageurl);
            }
        });
    }
```