# Unable to get download url from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting this error when trying to retrieve image from firebase storage.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete on upload task.
```

Code:-

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

filePath.putFile(imageUri)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String downloadUri = filePath.getDownloadUrl().getResult().toString();
                UserRef.child("profileImage").setValue(downloadUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                         if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                             Intent selfIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                             startActivity(selfIntent);
                             Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile image uploaded to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             progressDialog.dismiss();
                         } 
                         else {
                             String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                             Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error Occurred" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             progressDialog.dismiss();
                         }
                      }
                  });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Simone, could you please rephrase your question? It is not really clear what's your problem here! Thanks!

Comment: Improved formatting, make it clear to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`filePath.getDownloadUrl()` returns a Task that tracks the asynchronous work required to get the url.  You can't just call `getResult()` on it immediately - you have to listen to its results like your are currently with `putFile()`.

Read this for more information: [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)