# firebase / glide creating a reference of a image and displaying it

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide

I am attempting to have the user upload an image and then have it then displayed as a profile picture. I am able to upload the image to firebase successfully but I am not able to display it I am following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl) 
The current problem i am facing is on how to successfully get the image url to be able to display it

the current state of the code

```
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

//Android Layout

private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
private TextView mName;
private TextView mStatus;

private Button mStatusBtn;
private Button mImageBtn;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

private StorageReference mImageStorage;

private Context context = user_profile.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
    mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_user_name);
    mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_user_status);

    mStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_change_status_btn);
    mImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_change_image_btn);
    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).toString();
            String status = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue()).toString();
            String image = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue()).toString();

            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String status_value = mStatus.getText().toString();

            Intent status_intent = new Intent(user_profile.this, change_status.class);
            status_intent.putExtra("status_value", status_value);
            startActivity(status_intent);

        }
    });

    mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Image"), GALLERY_PICK);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String imageUri = data.getDataString();

        CropImage.activity(Uri.parse(imageUri))
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog((user_profile.this));
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Pleas Stand By");
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

            StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + (".jpeg"));
            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        final String download_url = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    Glide
                                            .with(context)
                                            .load()
                                            .into(mDisplayImage);

                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(user_profile.this, "Succesful Upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(user_profile.this, "Error Up Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }

}


public String niceRefLink (String date){

    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child("profile_images");
    return dateRef.toString();
}}
```

I believe the issue is with this block of code

```
    public String niceRefLink (String date){

    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference dateRef = storageRef.child("profile_images");
    return dateRef.toString();
}}
```

When the image is attempted to be displayed glide says that it is unable to locate the image this is how my database is looking 
[image: database]

I tried to use the method niceRefLink to display the image but I was unsuccessful i have also tried the download_url string i have created but also did not work

[image: Database]

HI, i tried the answer you submitted but I am still having issues the image is successfully getting uploaded to the database but it is still not getting displayed when i run the app i am getting the toast upload successful but the image stays as the preview image.

```
private String mImageUri;

    private void getUserInfo(){
    mUserDatabase.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                if(map.get("image")!=null){
                    mImageUri = map.get("image").toString();
                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(mImageUri).into(mDisplayImage);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: you store the image url in firebase realtime database .

Comment: the image is already in the database yes. The problem I am having is retrieving that URL in the code to be able to display it

Comment: can you put the  realtime database screenshot?

Comment: database screenshot has been added

Comment: This image url not a perfect url this is only a string. url alwasy start the http .

Comment: copy this "final String download_url = task.getDownloadUrl().toString();" and replace   " final String download_url = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
"

Comment: This is perfectly store your image url in realtime firebase databse. then you retrieve the url

Comment: Hope it's help full for you.

Comment: updated code above

Comment: what you get the mImageUri ?

Comment: That is my problem i dont know what to put for it right now i just have private String mImageUri; this is the problem I am facing

Comment: can you contact me personally? so i'm help you.

Comment: sure send me your email or preferred contact means

Comment: chetanmahajan850@gmail.com this is my email id.

Answer (score 0):

This code is, How to get image url and how to display in ImageView.

```
  private void getUserInfo(){
        mCustomerDatabase.child("Users").child(current_uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    if(map.get("image")!=null){
                        mProfileImageUrl = map.get("image").toString();
                        Glide.with(getApplication()).load(mProfileImageUrl).into(profileImage);
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }

        });

    }
```

Hope it's help full and Enjoy.