# How can I access a file on firebase storage by the download url when I just have access to the file name?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

So, I just want to swap some things in the download url to make users be able to search for files in the storage. it's just that I don't want to swap the long code in the end, because then users will have to use that super long code. I have to use the url to access the files.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialmedia- 
1df9e.appspot.com/o/images%2Flego?alt=media&token=4cc05dec-8dda-4f46-a8a7- 
eb1bf916c512                  ⇈                              ⇈
                            swap this                      Not this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported to construct your own download URLs.  You should be using the Firebase SDK to generate download URLs that are special for each file you want to download.

Comment: How do I use the firebase sdk to generate special urls?

Comment: What does a url like that look like?

Comment: If you're using the Android SDK, you buidld a reference to the file in storage that you want to download, then call getDownloadUrl to get a Task that resolves to the string of the URL.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But how can I change the look/parts/construction of the url?

Comment: As I said, it's not supported to build your own URLs.  You should call the API, and assume that the URL cannot be changed or reconstructed.