# Get Image Download url by Passing Firebase Storage Reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

**Is it Possible to get Download uri by using Firebase Storage Reference ?**

This is question not similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)

Above question problem was get image url by uploading image.

I want to try something get Image Download URI by providing Image Ref from Storage.

I tried something :

```
storageReference.child("images/download.jpg").downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                if (uri != null){
                    Log.e("url", uri.toString())
                }
            }
```

Image :

[image]

It shows Error (i know something like that does not exist) :

> E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not
>   Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
>       java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:74)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

I am just looking for show image without using `glide` library. so i am looking for image uri to show image.

Comment: That error message is saying that the file you referenced doesn't exist in storage.

Comment: The error message is saying otherwise.  Read it carefully.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry sir it was my fault another image url was different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("storage ref url in string");
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                //do your stuff- uri.toString() will give you download URL\\
            }
        });
```

or directly use StorageReference if you already initialized it.