# Error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl() of type firebase.storage.Uploadtask.tasksnapshot

Tags: java, firebase-storage

mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                     .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {

```
     @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   @Override
    public void run() {
     mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
      }
      }, 500);

 Toast.makeText(bloodsignform.this, "Upload successful", 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                    }
```

Comment: Where in your code is `getDownloadUrl()` method? At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)