# Is there a way to store an image to firestore as a String with working url link?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I store an actual image on the firebase storage and then I also store String of Uri to firestore. I want to use Glide library to retrieve an image, but I need my app to store working url to firestore for that.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Check out this [Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7puuTDSf3pk) on how to upload and display public image URLs on Android. You can then store this URL in the Firestore.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) and store that in the database.

This has been [discussed in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379251) on Stack Overflow.