# IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete: adding data from Firebase to a pin in google maps Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

First off im very new to java and developing in general.

Im trying to show information (from Firebase) to a clickable pin in my google maps project. When i click the stored pin on the map i get following error: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete.

This is the following code that makes the error:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataValues : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final Pin myPin = dataValues.getValue(Pin.class);
                    final String pinReference = dataValues.getKey();
                    try {
                        MarkerOptions pinMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myPin.pinLocation.latitude, myPin.pinLocation.longitude));
                        pinMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo_pin));
                        mMap.addMarker(pinMarker);
                        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                                Uri storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference("pictures").child(pinReference + ".jpeg").getDownloadUrl().getResult();

                                Fragment fragment = new PinInfoFragment(myPin.placeName, firebaseUser.getEmail(), myPin.comment, storageReference, myPin.placeRating);
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.include_center_fragment, fragment);
                                return true;
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I have following code in a class fragment to display the information to the pin:

```
public class PinInfoFragment extends Fragment {

    String placeName;
    String name;
    String comment;
    Uri photoURL;
    double ratings;

    PinInfoFragment(String placeName, String name, String comment, Uri photoURL, double ratings){
        this.placeName = placeName;
        this.name = name;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.photoURL = photoURL;
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    TextView placeNameTextView;
    TextView nameTextView;
    TextView commentTextView;
    ImageView photoImageView;
    TextView ratingsTextView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pin_info, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        placeNameTextView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_name);
        nameTextView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_name_user);
        commentTextView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_user_comment);
        photoImageView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_image);
        ratingsTextView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_rating);

        placeNameTextView.setText(placeName);
        nameTextView.setText(name);
        commentTextView.setText(comment);
        Glide.with(this).load(photoURL).into(photoImageView);
        ratingsTextView.setText("* " + ratings);

        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_exit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pin_info_layout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the stack trace of the error output (The output that had the "`java.lang.IllegalStateException`" text in it).  So we can see what classes led up to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is causing the problem:

```
Uri storageReference = firebaseStorage
    .getReference("pictures")
    .child(pinReference + ".jpeg")
    .getDownloadUrl()
    .getResult();
```

`getDownloadUrl` doesn't return a URL immediately.  It returns a Task that you need to listen to in order to get the result asynchronously.  You can only call `getResult` on the task after it completes.

Please read the answer to this question to see how it works: [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)

Comment: Perfekt! This answer and the link you provided help me solve the problem! Thanks, Doug.