# Kotlin FirebaseStorage getDownloadUrl error

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

Hi i want to get downloadUrl but i got error
I'm tried some methods like this

`var firebaseURL =p0?.uploadSessionUri.toString()` the result is **url** but if i open this url, i get this error  `Invalid request.  X-Goog-Upload-Command header is missing.`
 ( i'm new in kotlin)

```
uploadTo.addOnSuccessListener (object :OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>{

        override fun onSuccess(p0: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?) {

            var firebaseURL =p0.downloadUrl // i got error in this line

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid!!)
                .child("imagurl")
                .setValue(firebaseURL.toString())

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloadUrl "property" here is not actually a property at all.  It's a method called [getDownloadUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) that returns another Task that asynchronously fetches the URL.  It doesn't return a URL directly.  Refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) on how to use it correctly.  For example:

```
val ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg")
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file)

val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
        task.exception?.let {
            throw it
        }
    }
    ref.downloadUrl
}.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val downloadUri = task.result
    } else {
        // Handle failures
        // ...
    }
}
```

What's happening here is:

1. The file is being uploaded with `uploadTask`.
2. A continuation is added to that Task as a callback when it's complete
3. ref.downloadUrl returns another Task to get the URL.
4. Another callback is added to the chain to handle the fetched URL.

See also: [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)

The fact of the matter is that this API was not very well designed.  The method starts with "get" but is not really a property getter.