# Kotlin - get Firebase Image DownloadUrl returns "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu"

Tags: kotlin, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload images to Real time Firebase Database by creating two folders using Compressor library and need to display image like messenger with username but i am unable to display image due to url issue

```
            var filePath = mStorageRef!!.child("chat_profile_images")
                .child(userId + ".jpg")

            //Create another directory for thumbimages ( smaller, compressed images)
            var thumbFilePath = mStorageRef!!.child("chat_profile_images")
                .child("thumbs")
                .child(userId + ".jpg")


            filePath.putFile(resultUri)
                .addOnCompleteListener{
                        task: Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {

                        //Let's get the pic url
                        var donwloadUrl = task.result?.storage?.downloadUrl.toString()

                        Log.d(TAG, "Profilepic link: $donwloadUrl")

                        //Upload Task
                        var uploadTask: UploadTask = thumbFilePath
                            .putBytes(thumbByteArray)

                        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener{
                                task: Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> ->
                            var thumbUrl = task.getResult()?.storage?.downloadUrl.toString()

                            Log.d(TAG, "Profilepic link: $thumbUrl")
```

i tried to change downloadUrl

```
filepath.downloadUrl.toString
thumbFilePath.downloadUrl.toString
```

but both these values getting "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu"

i also tried to change

```
task.result.sessionurl.downloadUrl.toString
```

for this one i am getting downloadUrl but not a complete solution for my problem as still i cannot display image i need to get thumbUrl downloadUrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the exact same and very common misunderstanding as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl), except it's in java.  You should [follow the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) to understand get [getDownloadUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) works.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it's not a property getter, it's actually a method that returns a `Task<Uri>` that tracks the asynchronous fetch of the URL you want, just like the upload task:

```
filePath.downloadUrl
.addOnSuccessListener { urlTask ->
    // download URL is available here
    val url = urlTask.result.toString()
}.addOnFailureListener { e ->
    // Handle any errors
}
```

This will only work after the upload is fully complete.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct way of getting download link after uploading**

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061743/7795072)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting out there, I also encounter the same problem,

> but both these values getting "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu"

but it wasn't the same mistake from the OP

used **addOnCompleteListener** instead of **addOnSuccesslistener**

My Error code:

```
imageRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { url ->
                val imageURL = url.toString()
                println("imageURL: $imageURL , url: $url")
                addUserToDatabase(imageURL)
            }
```