# Kotlin - Firebase - Save Uri to user's folder images keeps saving wrong Uri

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to build an Instagram-like app, an issue occurs when I try to save taken photo to user's folder "images" on Firebase database. It keeps saving something like "com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask@62873ce"

Instead of link like this:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gramgram-1b3f9.appspot.com/o/users%2F7q3pqR6GnHMx7NSdgoBqZETkrS32%2Fphoto?alt=media&token=bbcbe556-1de5-4176-aba2-599f829e65"

here is my Share Activity.kt

```
class ShareActivity : BaseActivity(2) {
    private val TAG = "ShareActivity"
    private lateinit var mCamera: CameraHelper
    private lateinit var mFirebase: FirebaseHelper


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")

        mFirebase =FirebaseHelper(this)

        mCamera = CameraHelper(this)
        mCamera.takeCameraPicture()

        back_image.setOnClickListener{finish()}
        share_text.setOnClickListener{share()}
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == mCamera.REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                GlideApp.with(this).load(mCamera.imageUri).centerCrop().into(post_image)
            } else{
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun share(){
        val imageUri = mCamera.imageUri
        if (imageUri != null){
            val uid = mFirebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
            mFirebase.storage.child("users").child(uid).child("images")
                .child(imageUri.lastPathSegment!!).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful){
                        mFirebase.database.child("images").child(uid).push()
                            .setValue(it.toString())
                            .addOnCompleteListener{
                                if (it.isSuccessful){
                                    startActivity(Intent(this,
                                        ProfileActivity::class.java))
                                    finish()
                                } else {
                                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

here are my uploadUserPhoto and updateUsePhoto functions in FirebaseHelper.kt

```
fun uploadUserPhoto(photo: Uri, onSuccess: (String) -> Unit) {
    val uTask = storage.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/photo").putFile(photo)
        storage.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/photo").putFile(photo)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            uTask.continueWithTask { _ ->
                storage.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/photo").downloadUrl
            }.addOnCompleteListener{
                if (it.isSuccessful && it.result != null) {
                    onSuccess(it.result.toString())
                } else {
                    activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


fun updateUserPhoto( photoUrl: String, onSuccess: () -> Unit){
    database.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/photo").setValue(photoUrl)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                onSuccess()
            } else {
                activity.showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
            }
        }
}
```

I am not sure how to set my `private fun share()` to upload correct URL to User's "images" folder

and here is my CameraHelper.kt

```
class CameraHelper(private val activity: Activity){
var imageUri: Uri? = null
val REQUEST_CODE = 1
private val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
    Locale.US
)

fun takeCameraPicture() {
    val intent =
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
        val imageFile = createImageFile()
        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity,
            "com.example.homeactivity.fileprovider",
            imageFile
        )
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}

private fun createImageFile(): File {
    val storageDir: File? = activity.getExternalFilesDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
    )
    return File.createTempFile(
        "JPEG_${simpleDateFormat.format(Date())}_",
        ".jpg",
        storageDir
    )
}
```

}

Comment: `setValue(it.toString())` -- `it` here I think is your `UploadTask`. I haven't used Firebase Realtime Database in about a year, but I doubt that you call `toString()` on the `UploadTask` to get the URL.

Comment: Where are you calling uploadUserPhoto?

Comment: Tried that, it crashes the app and gives com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getResult @CommonsWare

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm calling it in another function for uploading profile picture, but I shared this code just for you guys to see the code that works correctly and I don't know how to set my Private fun share() to work like this

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the result from `putFile(imageUri)` correctly.  You have:

```
putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful){
        mFirebase.database.child("images").child(uid).push()
            .setValue(it.toString())
```

That `it.toString()` is not the URL.  `it` is the UploadTask object returned by `putFile()`.  You can't just turn that into a string - it's a Task that you need to observe to get the result.

You seem to be fetching a download URL correctly in `uploadUserPhoto` using `downloadUrl` to fetch the URL to write.  You're going to have to do it that way instead.

See also the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696034/kotlin-get-firebase-image-downloadurl-returns-com-google-android-gms-tasks-zz).

Comment: Tried that,removing toString() - it crashes the app and gives com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getResult

Comment: Tried what exactly?  This answer explains why what you have now doesn't work.  You're not fetching the download URL at all, except in `uploadUserPhoto`, which you're not even calling.  If you have other code that's not working, and it generates a whole a new error, I think that should go in a new question.

Comment: I'm new to programming so, I can't just follow the documentation you provided to me.
I removed toString() leaving only "it", and after I click on share photo, it crashes the app.
Also, I just wrote the "updateUserPhoto" in the hope that someone will tell me how to fix my private fun share() the way "updateUserPhoto" is fixed

Comment: That wasn't my recommended solution.  You need to use downloadUrl to fetch the download URL from a reference in the same way that you're using in `uploadUserPhoto` and both links that I provided.

Comment: Doug, thanks for pointing that out, but I'm new to programming so, I can't just follow the documentation you provided to me. I asked for help because I don't know how to do that myself.. :/

Comment: I pointed out that you already know how to fetch the download URL - you are doing it in the `uploadUserPhoto` you posted in your question.  The linked question also gives code samples.  You can adapt these to fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it.
In case anyone needs it, here is working function share():

```
private fun share(){
    val imageUri = mCamera.imageUri
    if (imageUri != null){
        val uid = mFirebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
        val uTask = mFirebase.storage.child("users").child(uid).child("images").child(imageUri.lastPathSegment!!).putFile(imageUri)
        mFirebase.storage.child("users").child(uid).child("images").child(imageUri.lastPathSegment!!).putFile(imageUri)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    uTask.continueWithTask { _ ->
                        mFirebase.storage.child("users").child(uid).child("images")
                            .child(imageUri.lastPathSegment!!).downloadUrl
                    }.addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful && it.result != null)
                            mFirebase.database.child("images").child(uid).push()
                                .setValue(it.result.toString())
                                .addOnCompleteListener {
                                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                        startActivity(
                                            Intent(
                                                this,
                                                ProfileActivity::class.java
                                            )
                                        )
                                        finish()
                                    } else {
                                        showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                                    }
                                }
                    }
                } else {
                    showToast(it.exception!!.message!!)
                }
            }
    }
}
```