# Cloud Storage: downloadUrl Type mismatch: inferred type is Task<Uri!> but Uri! was expected

Tags: firebase, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-storage

I've just started learning android development with Kotlin. I'm trying to implement MVVM in my project.

Message: Type mismatch. Required:Uri! Found:Task

I have a question: how to cast a Task in the Url! ???

I have ViewModel:

```html
class AddVehicleViewModel(private val vehicleRepository: VehicleRepository,
                          onFailureListener: OnFailureListener): BaseViewModel(onFailureListener) {
    private val _mkVehicleCompletedEvent = SingleLiveEvent<Unit>()
    val mkVehicleCompletedEvent = _mkVehicleCompletedEvent
    val user = vehicleRepository.getUser()

    fun mkVehicle(user: User, imageUri: Uri?, auto: String) {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            vehicleRepository.uploadVehicleImage(user.uid, imageUri).onSuccessTask { downloadUrl ->
                Tasks.whenAll(
                    vehicleRepository.createVehicle(user.uid, mkListVehicle(user, auto, downloadUrl.toString()))
                )
            }.addOnCompleteListener {
                _mkVehicleCompletedEvent.call()
            }.addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener)
        }
    }

    private fun mkListVehicle(user: User, auto: String, imageUri: String): DataVehicles {
        return DataVehicles(
            uid = user.uid,
            image = imageUri,
            auto = auto,
            username = user.username,
            city = user.city.toString()
        )
    }
}
```

and repository:

```html
class FirebaseVehicleRepository : VehicleRepository {
    override fun uploadVehicleImage(uid: String, imageUri: Uri): Task<Uri> =
        task { taskSource ->
            storage.child("users").child(uid).child("images")
                .child(imageUri.lastPathSegment.toString()).putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    taskSource.setResult(it.result!!.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl)
                } else {
                    taskSource.setException(it.exception!!)
                }
            }
        }
```

The error is flashing on this line of code:

```html
taskSource.setResult(it.result!!.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't cast a Task to a Uri.  The "property" `downloadUrl` is actually an asynchronous Java method called [getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) which returns a Task.  You need to use attach a listener to the Task to get the Uri, just like you did when you called `putFile()`, which also returns a Task.

Use the pattern shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url):

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
}.addOnFailureListener {
    // Handle any errors
}
```

For your case, use `it.result!!.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener`...

Also see the java language equivalent: [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to do it