# What does this mean download_url = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
StorageReference filePath = employee_photo_profile_reference.child(current_employee_ID+".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(result_uri).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() { 

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(activity_setup.this,"Profile Photo stored Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (task.getResult() != null){ 

                                final String download_url = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Comment: this will give you a `link` to download/get the file you just uploaded. you should upload it to `firestore` so you can easily access it again, if it is a profile picture you should add this to the user document, you can load image from this like via any image loading lib

Comment: @RahulGaur Actually, it's not doing that.  It's an incorrect use of getDownloadURL.

Answer (score 1):

That line of code is buggy.  It's incorrectly using `getDownloadUrl()`.  This is a **very common** mistake - you can't just call `toString()` on the result to get a URL.

[getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) returns a Task object which you can use to fetch the download URL asynchronously.

The correct usage is demonstrated here: [How to get URL from Firebase Storage getDownloadURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37374868)

I also suggested [reading the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url).