# How do i retrieve firebase downloadURLs

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage

I've been struggling for a while, but without success. My question is simple, how do I retrieve an `ArrayList<Uri>` of download URIs and be able to use this `ArrayList` later on since this task is asynchronous? I've tried using a callback, but it's not working.

For example this

```
   public getAllDownloadURIs(final FirestoreCallback 
                                                  firestoreCallback) {
   final ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

   for (StorageReference storageReference : referencesToFiles) {
            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    uris.add(uri);
                }
            });
            firestoreCallback.onCallback(uris);
        }
```

```
    private interface FirestoreCallback {
        void onCallback(List<Uri> uris);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your path once and for more reference check out link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37379251/10838454