# Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException facing glide is not working to load image from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-glide

I am trying to load image from firebase storage to my recyclerview. In `onBindViewHolder` method I have implemented below code to load the image. But I am facing strange problem. Already I have seen some of similar problem's solutions but none of them worked.

**Code**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AlternateListHolder_Market holder, int position) {

        productsListOfMarketFirestore curretItem = filterList.get(position);
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://app-31e06.appspot.com/user_image1/").child(curretItem.getProductId() + ".jpg");
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
                .load(storageReference)
                .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

**Error**

```
E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://app-31e06.appspot.com/user_image1/1111.jpg
        at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getModelLoaders(Registry.java:584)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadData(DecodeHelper.java:205)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getCacheKeys(DecodeHelper.java:223)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:302)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:233)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

Comment: In load("...") you need to pass image link. If you are taking image location from firebase storage then first get all the link in a List and then pass it to the adapter class.

Comment: I am passing storage reference here. Image location is already initialized in ```storageReference```.

Comment: Log the value of storage Reference. Check, if it is returning image URL of 1111.jpg or not.

Comment: unfortunately no. How should I fix this?how can i get URL from storage reference? isn't it possible!!.. or  is there any other way to do this?

Comment: actually it's giving me something like this "gs://app-31e06.appspot.com/user_image1/1111.jpg" which i have initialized before. should pass the http link to load("..") method??

Comment: The link which storeReference is having is the location of your storage on Google cloud. This is what I said above that load() method needs an image url to download and display image. In order to get image link of 1111.jpg , you need to gets It's url from firebase storage.

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl

Comment: After getting the url you just pass it to load() method