# Populating a RecycleView with images from Storage References with Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

The image is not showing up, the context is passed from the activity with the recycleView on the Adapter Constructor.

The error code is :

```
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://my-data-7pt42.appspot.com/CompanyImages/aMBvmcvfh6RCwGn3n0WYCYY7Nxo1/logo.jpg
```

What I'm trying is :

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        StorageReference reference = firebaseStorage.getReference().child("CompanyImages/"+idParser.get(position)+"/logo.jpg");

        holder.companyName.setText(allCompanies.get(position));

        Glide.with(context)
        .load(reference)
        .into(holder.imageRowCompany);

    }
```

I also tried replacing `context` with `holder.imageRowCompany.getContext()`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you will log the value of `reference` , it will not return an Image URL of `logo.png`,instead you will get the location of your file on google cloud.

You need to get image url of `logo.png`.
Here you can check how to get the download url of any file from firebase. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I wonder what [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) documentation is for thought?

Comment: I just noticed , by using FirebaseUI we can directly pass the storageReference to load() method of glide to load the image.But It's strange why your code didn't work. From what I know Glide needs a secured image link i.e HTTPS to load the image and your reference  variable wasn't having a secured image link.