# How to show images from Firebase into RecyclerView with Picasso

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get all the images stored in the firebase storage but it doesn't show the images neither there is any kind of error or warnings it just shows an empty recycler view

*Here is the image of the screen is see*
[image]

**Java Files**

*Search_Fragment.java*

```
 public class Search_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public  List<Upload> mUploads;
    PostAdapter postsAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        RecyclerView postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerView);
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(),mUploads);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

        //This are images that i tried manual ly and it worked fine
//        List<PostItem> postItems = new ArrayList<>();
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image1));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image2));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image3));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image4));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image5));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image7));
//        postItems.add(new PostItem(R.drawable.image9));

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failiur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

*PostAdapter.java* //adapter

```
    public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    private final Context mContext;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mUploads = uploads;
        mContext = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item_container, parent,false);
        return new PostViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                .borderColor(Color.WHITE)
                .borderWidthDp(5)
                .cornerRadiusDp(13)
                .oval(false)
                .build();
        Picasso.get()
                .load(mUploads.get(position).getmImageUrl())
                .fit()
                .transform(transformation)
                .into(holder.postImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RoundedImageView postImageView;

        PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);
        }

    }
}
```

*Upload.Java* //model for storing imageuri in strings

```
public class Upload {
    private String mImageUrl;


    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String imageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }
}
```

*Upload_Fragment.java*

```
    public class Upload_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 10;
    private ImageView uploadImageView;
    private Uri mImageUri;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false);
        Button chooseImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_button);
        Button uploadImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        uploadImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_view);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        chooseImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> openFileChooser());
        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                uploadToFirebase(mImageUri);
            }


        });

        return view;
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(uploadImageView);

        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            reference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
                                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                                });
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                        double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Ocurred" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The url you used it wrong

Comment: what should i use can u tell me

Comment: You get download url from firebase storage. If you have path stored somewhere. You can find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/how-to-get-url-from-firebase-storage-getdownloadurl) here.

Comment: but i don't want to download the images to the user device I just want to show it

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-offline-uploaded-file-download-url-in-firebase/53300660#53300660) is a recommended way to get the download URL.

Comment: @SagarRawal Even if you don't want to download in user device you have to by using url

Comment: @Ashish ok I have checked I have implemented the get download URL correctly also retrieving images is done correctly nor errors no warning at all I have confirmed that does it stores the URL in the postItem.java model class with a log message but still, it doesn't show the images I'm stuck on this from last approx 10 days, should I update my code in the question so u can easily see what I have updated and why it doesn't work still

Comment: @Ashish i have updated the code please check it still doesn't work