# Passing non final objects to method references

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, expression-evaluation

What is the explanation that `s.get()` returns **"ONE"** the second time as well?

```
String x = "one";
Supplier<String> s = x::toUpperCase;
System.out.println("s.get() = " + s.get());
x = "two";
System.out.println("s.get() = " + s.get());
```

**Update:**

Compare it to:

```
String x = "one";
Supplier<String> s = () -> x.toUpperCase();
System.out.println("s.get() = " + s.get());
x = "two";
System.out.println("s.get() = " + s.get());
```

It will throw a compilation error.

Comment: Upvoted. This is more interesting than the simpler cases for which "cuz it's a reference, innit" is an appropriate answer.

Comment: @khelwood: *similar* I'd say. You could write something similar to `Supplier` in C++ that *would* output "TWO".

Comment: the second example should not compile

Answer (score 5):

In java variables referring an objects are usually called as `references`. In the above code you have two references , `x` and `s`.

Strings are immutable and any change done, represents another Object. Once created you can not modify any state of the String object.

In the code both `x` and `s` are initilized to refer 2 objects and then `x` is made to refer another object, but `s` still refers to same object. note that `::` is evaluated immediately and resulting object is assiged. `x` can change its reference to another object independent of `y`

Using `x = "two"` only makes `x` to refer to a different object.

Answer (score 3):

String is an inmutable class and you are doing

```
x = "two";
```

keeping the object **s** *"intact"* with the previous value "ONE"

Answer (score 3):

Passing final or effectively final variables is required only by lambda expressions ([the reasons why it works so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299889/4922375)). With method references, which are evaluated differently,

> [15.13.3. Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4)
>
> When a method reference expression *has an expression* (rather than a type) preceding the `::` separator, that subexpression is evaluated immediately. The result of evaluation is stored until the method of the corresponding functional interface type is invoked; at that point, the result is used as the target reference for the invocation. This means the expression preceding the `::` separator is evaluated only when the program encounters the method reference expression, and *is not re-evaluated on subsequent invocations on the functional interface type*.

so it is not necessary that a variable has to be a `final`.

Actually, it has no matter whether a class is immutable. Rather, it is important if the left part of a method reference is an expression or not.

I would like to show a short example to make you understand:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Supplier<A> supplier1 = A::new; // (1)
        Supplier<A> supplier2 = new A()::self; // (2) 

        A r1 = supplier1.get(); // (3)
        A r2 = supplier2.get(); // (4)
    }

    private A self() { return this; }

}
```

1. A supplier instance has been created, the result has not been evaluated yet (*a method reference with a type*).
2. A supplier and its result have been calculated (*a method reference with the `new A()` expression*).
3. For each `supplier1.get()` call, it will be re-evaluated.
4. The result from step 2 will be returned.

Comment: Does it mean that toUpperCase methods is called only once on "one" instance?

Comment: @StephenL., the method will be called 2 times, but the result will be evaluated only once (when the program encounters the method reference expression). I highlighted it in the answer

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question so I ran it through a decompiler - but the answer supports Andrew Tobilko answer

```
java -jar cfr_0_119.jar LambdaTest --decodelambdas false

/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_119.
 */
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class LambdaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "one";
        Supplier<String> s = (Supplier<String>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(null, null, null, ()Ljava/lang/Object;, toUpperCase(), ()Ljava/lang/String;)((String)x);
        System.out.println("s.get() = " + s.get());
        x = "two";
        System.out.println("s.get() = " + s.get());
    }
}
```

So the method reference is getting a copy of the first instance of x which is why it outputs "ONE" twice, and a static lambda isnt created, only a call to toUpper

I also ran the second example which does create a lambda(I missed out the part that doesnt compile -

```
java -jar cfr_0_119.jar LambdaTest --decodelambdas false
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_119.
 */
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class LambdaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String y = "one";
        Supplier<String> sy = (Supplier<String>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(null, null, null, ()Ljava/lang/Object;, lambda$0(java.lang.String ), ()Ljava/lang/String;)((String)y);
        System.out.println("sy.get() = " + sy.get());
    }

    private static /* synthetic */ String lambda$0(String string) {
        return string.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable:

```
String x = "one";
Supplier<String> s = x::toUpperCase;
```

is equivalent to:

```
String x = "one";
Supplier<String> s = "one"::toUpperCase;
```

Answer (score -1):

You created a `Supplier`, which just supplies values, and in this case the same value every time, because the value of `x` here is only converted once when the lambda is created.

What you want is a `Function`, something that takes an argument and returns a result.

Try this:

```
String x = "one";
Function<String, String> s = String::toUpperCase;
System.out.println("s.apply(x) = " + s.apply(x));
x = "two";
System.out.println("s.apply(x) = " + s.apply(x));
```

Comment: I created Supplier for a reason to have a method reference to the instance.

Comment: Well, the instance is a String with text "one".  It will therefore never change, as Strings are immutable.  You might as well have written: "one"::toUpperCase.