# LibGDX trying to create a method that handles click input on a sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

So this is my code, the problem lies in the timer, I get an error saying that `timesClicked` is accessed from within inner class, therefore needs to be declared `final`.

However, if I declare it `final`, I won't be able to change it. So what do I do?

```
public static void displayItem(Player Dawid, Item item, int timesClicked, Sprite itemSprite){
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

        camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        if (Assets.healthPotionSPR.getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (timesClicked == 1){
                Shop.checkRequirement(item.getBuyPrice(), Dawid, item);
                Dawid.setGold(Dawid.getGold() - HealthPotion.buyPrice);
                item.setStock(item.getStock()+1);
                topText = "Kupiłeś eliksir zdrowia!";
            }
            Assets.sellText = item.getSellPrice() + "g";
            Assets.buyText = item.getBuyPrice() + "g";
            timesClicked++;
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timesClicked = 0;
                }
            }, 500);

        }
    }
}
```

I want to create this method, and I need to be able to provide a static int that would be eddited depending on amounts of clicks and time between each click.

**EDIT**

ok I got it, so there's a public static int timesClicked, then the method goes :

```
  public static void displayItem(Player Dawid, Item item, int timesClicked, Sprite itemSprite){

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

        camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        if (itemSprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            if (timesClicked == 1){
                Shop.checkRequirement(item.getBuyPrice(), Dawid, item);



            }
            Assets.sellText = item.getSellPrice() + "g";
            Assets.buyText = item.getBuyPrice() + "g";
            spriteClicked++;
            timesClicked = spriteClicked;
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    spriteClicked = 0;
                }
            }, 500);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am very confused. The problem is I am referring to an undefined int, that will be entered into this method once I call the method, so the solutions in the thread you sent me didn't help me unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [MutableObject](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableObject.html) or something similar. If you don't use Apache Commons you can simply create one like this:

```
public class MutableInt {
  public int value;

  public int get() {
    return value;
  }

  public void set(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

This way you can create a `MutableInt` and declare it final, but you will still be able to change the int value in it:

```
// declare this somewhere in the top of your method
final MutableInt clicked = new MutableInt();
clicked.set(timesClicked); // initialize

// ... other code

// replaces "timesClicked++;"
clicked.set(clicked.get() + 1); // or maybe write an "increase" method for this ...

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
      // replaces "timesClicked = 0;"
      clicked.set(0); // no problem anymore, because "clicked" is final
    }
  }, 500);
```

---

BTW: Maybe I get this wrong, but it seems like you are trying to change the value of `timesClicked` in the calling method. But `timesClicked` only exists in the `displayItem` method, so whenever the method is called again, the value of `timesClicked` will be reset, so it will never be more than 1.
Maybe try using a global field instead of a method parameter.

**EDIT:**

If you want to change the value "timesClicked" of another object, you can use the reference of this object instead of the int parameter like this:

```
public static void displayItem(Player Dawid, Item item, HealthPotionClicked variableHoldingObject, Sprite itemSprite){
  // ...
  variableHoldingObject.setTimesClicked(variableHoldingObject.getTimesClicked() + 1);

  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
    public void run() {
      variableHoldingObject.setTimesClicked(0);
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

This way you won't even need the `MutableObject`.

Comment: Tobias it is interesting what you've just said. You are correct, timesClicked is taken from an integer from the larger class, e.g "healthPotionClicked", so no matter what I do, I won't be able to change healthPotionClicked in this method? What solution would you suggest in this case?

Comment: @DawidKaim You can use a reference of the "healthPotionClicked" object instead of the integer parameter. I edited the answer to add an example.

Comment: Thank you so much Tobias! I made it :)